# How to add preformatted text to a post message

Tags: support, markdown, design

I'm already trying with the tag pre but doesn't working

example:

```
public static bool testFunction()
{
  //some commented code
  return true;
}
```

The "return true" and other keywords must be blue

Comment: Are you asking about formatting your question posts on StackOverflow? If so, check out the meta site (http://meta.stackoverflow.com/), where questions *about* the site (and posting on it) are addressed.

Comment: Don't use `<pre>`. Add 4 spaces before code.

Comment: i thought he was asking about SO, but the question itself doesn't have `pre` in it, and the tag is `html`. maybe it's just poorly worded?

Comment: what's SO?
I'm gonna try with 4 spaces before the code
    public static bool test()
    {
        return true;
    }

Comment: 4 spaces before the code do nothing
i'm gonna try with "code" tag
<code>
 return false;
</code>

Comment: Work perfectly with 4 spaces before the code but not in a comment. Only in the post of the answers

Comment: This seems to belong on meta...

Comment: yea this dont belong

Comment: But how do you preformat text that is _not_ code, but which might contain HTML? Typical example would be output or logs from a program that give necessary information in a question or answer. `>` quotes do not work, the `pre` tag does not work, and 4 spaces colour it as code.

Answer (score 1):

Dude just read the [full reference](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) on how to format your text.

Comment: I don't know what's happened but now I'm watching my first post with the blue keywords that is correct...

I'm using the pre tag with de property lang="cs" cause is c# code

let me try again
<pre lang="cs" >
private void test()
{
    test2.add();
}
</pre>

Comment: <pre>
public static bool test()
{
    return true;
    //some commented code
}
</pre>

Comment: someone edited your post to correct the formatting.

Answer (score 1):

Since the [changes to syntax highlighting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/72082/changes-to-syntax-highlighting) in December 2010, the *highlighting* is based on the tags on the question. Hence examples of code blocks in this very question will not show any highlighting unless some fake language tag like `java` or `html` is added to the question. (They will show *preformatted* text using a `monotype` font though; just not coloured.)

Answer (score 0):

Testing now with 4 spaces before the code

```
return false;

public static void testFunction()
{
}
```

Answer (score 0):

4 spaces before the code works great here in Stack Overflow, but in other sites will work too?

Comment: If they use Markdown, yes. If they don't, who knows? (Name a specific site and it becomes possible to answer.)

Comment: @Donal, the syntax highlighting is not a Markdown feature, but is using client side [Google Code Prettify](http://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/).