# Changes to syntax highlighting

Tags: discussion, tags, syntax-highlighting

> locked for the history - please post bugs and feature-requests separately.
>
> -Shog9

We're changing the way syntax highlighting is done on the Stack Exchange engine.

As you probably know, we use [Google Code Prettify](https://github.com/google/code-prettify) for automatic syntax highlighting.

Since the beginning, we've had kind of a boolean setting **per website**:

1. code blocks are *always* automatically highlighted (Stack Overflow, programmers.se, etc)
2. code blocks are *never* highlighted (Super User, photo.se, bicycles.se, etc)

We are now moving to a **more tag-based syntax highlighting** method. There are one of three possible syntax highlighting hints associated with each tag:

1. *specific* language hint -- tell prettify to use that language
2. *default* language hint -- let prettify infer a language
3. *null* -- no hint, no syntax highlighting

(all specific languages must be in the [set that prettify supports](https://github.com/google/code-prettify/blob/master/README.md), obviously)

> bsh, c, cc, cpp, cs, csh, cyc, cv, htm, html,
>     java, js, m, mxml, perl, pl, pm, py, rb, sh,
>     xhtml, xml, xsl.

[extensions available](https://github.com/google/code-prettify/tree/master/src) are

> apollo, css, go, hs, lisp, lua, ml, proto, scala, sql, vb, vhdl, wiki, yaml

Thus:

- If a question has no tags with a default or specific language hint, *no* syntax highlighting will be performed.
- If a question has at most one tag with a specific language hint, plus any number of default or null hints, then syntax highlighting will be performed only for that *specific* language.
- If a question has two tags that both define specific languages, it uses *default* and lets prettify infer as it always has.
- As long as a question has one or more tags with default language hints, but none with a specific language hint, it uses *default* and let prettify infer as it always has.

The default tag syntax highlighting hint is *null*. So the question is, **which tags should have the *default* and *specific language* hints?** I put my initial pass through the first 6 pages of tags here:

http://pastebin.com/AWMtu5rK

If you feel there should be changes, post your diffs as answers.

(and yes, there are plans to allow [an explicit override syntax](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/63800/interface-options-for-specifying-language-prettify) but for now we want to try to get the defaults mostly correct before worrying about the edge conditions)

Comment: Note that two language tags with competing highlighted must be treated as equivalent to none. *Please* tell me that c highlighting and c++ highlighting are different. I'd love another reason to convince the language ambivalent masses not to conflate the two.

Comment: @dmckee "If a question has two tags that both define specific languages, it uses default and lets prettify infer as it always has."

Comment: they are a way to add language d for highlighting?

Comment: @bio only if it is supported by Google Prettify

Comment: is objective-c on there or are we supposed to use c/c++ highlighting?

Answer (score 14):

Maybe this sort of thing could be attached to the tagwiki system?

Comment: diamond moderators can now change syntax highlighting on a per-tag per-site basis. We're also looking at an in-source override syntax soon.

Answer (score 13):

One potential change: when an answer is posted, remember the default language at the time.

It would be really nasty to post an answer which was formatted appropriately, only to have someone remove a tag and turn the answer into badly-formatted (or even unformatted?) mush.

EDIT: Of course, edits make this even more complicated... should an edit take on the new default or not?

Comment: I think we will take a "wait and see what happens in practice" attitude here. However, I do suspect that some of the syntax highlighting tag rules will result in *better* tagging, which is a net good for the community.

Comment: @Jeff: Wait and see sounds good to me... but I suspect it may also result in *worse* tagging, in that it may encourage the practice of tagging a question with the language the code is given in, even if the question has nothing to do with that language per se. For example, a question on how `StringBuilder` works shouldn't (IMO) really be tagged "c#" unless it's asking about the C# language itself. It's really a .NET question, just phrased using C#. Anyway, enough speculation....

Comment: but .net applies the "default" syntax highlighting per the rules.. http://pastebin.com/AWMtu5rK

Comment: @Jeff: Yes, indeed... but my point is that people may start tagging questions with the language by default. I guess VB would have been a better example here...

Comment: To support @Jon's point: that's exactly what I just did (http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/101307/why-does-syntax-highlighting-sometimes-not-work), even though I know that the question is not about C# per se, but it was the easiest solution.

Comment: On the other hand, there are so many questions tagged C# which are not about the language, or questions tagged ASP.NET which really are about web forms and not the ASP.NET framework...

Answer (score 6):

(Separate from my "general change" as they're different proposals.)

```
[iphone] = default
[c#-3.0] = default
[android] = default
[jquery] = default
[hibernate] = default
```

should be (IMO):

```
[iphone] = lang-c // Assume Objective-C for the most part
[c#-3.0] = lang-cs
[android] = lang-java
[jquery] = lang-js
[hibernate] = lang-java
```

(There may be more, but I need to go to work...)

Comment: this would be risky on "web soup" languages which tend to contain HTML, CSS, JavaScript, and XML pretty regularly -- if a language is specified it *forces* that language and will not detect any others. Generally we should only specify the language hint on a tag when the presence of that tag pretty reliably indicates that *ONLY* that language will ever be in any of those questions, at least 90% of the time..

Comment: @Jeff: That makes sense... and is a natural problem where (say) XML can come in just about any kind of question.

Comment: [iphone] should be Objective-C, as prettify supports Objective-C. Specifically, `lang-m`.

Answer (score 5):

Is it possible to have "related tags" feature that when certain tag is set on question, the syntax highlight will take into account additional tags that are always related?

For example, when `jQuery` tag is set, it's always good idea to also highlight "pure" JavaScript as well, so the highlighter should take into account both tags. Same with HTML, very often JavaScript/jQuery questions also involve HTML and such code is posted as well but [not rendered nicely](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/74628/inconsistent-highlighting-of-html-block) unless the `html` tag is explicitly included.

It's possible to manually edit each question and add those tags but would be nicer to have it done "behind the scenes" without the actual tags added.

Comment: this is what the "default" tag status already does, see above

Comment: @Jeff thanks, so this covers the jQuery/JavaScript issue but it would still be nice to have HTML highlighted when there is only `javascript` tag, as many times questions involving JavaScript also contain HTML code without really talking about HTML.

Comment: you misunderstand; "default" means it can infer ANY language including HTML. Just not 100% reliably.

Comment: @Jeff but `javascript` tag is not under the default category, so if a question contains only that tag and also have HTML code, the HTML code won't be highlighted correctly. For example this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4458119/display-save-as-dialog-and-save-contents-of-a-selected-text-inside-textarea-to/4458807 had only `javascript` tag so the HTML posted wasn't formatted well, only after I added `html` tag it was highlighted properly.

Comment: @Jeff, see also the screen capture at [Inconsistent highlighting of HTML block](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/74628/inconsistent-highlighting-of-html-block). It's a bit cumbersome to always *require* the `html` tag as well, when tagging `javascript` or `jquery`. As I think that `default` often works fine for JavaScript, maybe set `javascript` and `jquery` to use `default` rather than `lang-js`?

Answer (score 5):

This causes a potential problem with at least the [WordPress Answers](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/) site, as explained in [this meta question](https://wordpress.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/294/syntax-highlighting-doesnt-activate-without-language-tag). Basically, because the whole WordPress Answers site is about WordPress, the [wordpress] tag is almost never used, and thus, prettify will rarely be invoked, unless a specific language tag is also used. However, because WordPress is written in PHP, the [php] tag is also commonly left off of questions, so it's not uncommon to have a question with code in it that does not have a code-specific tag and does not have the [wordpress] tag.

Is it possible to cause all questions on WordPress Answers to invoke the "default" behavior, where prettify infers a language?

Answer (score 5):

c++0x should be highlighted as c++

```
[c++0x] = lang-c
```

Answer (score 5):

Pascal code (still) isn't getting highlighted, but should be.

```
[pascal] = default
```

Answer (score 4):

> ```
> [cl] = lang-lisp
> [el] = lang-lisp
> ```

This seems wrong. If I look at question tagged with `[cl]` or `[el]`, they have nothing to do with lisp. You probably meant `[common-lisp]` and `[emacs-lisp]`/`[elisp]` here (btw the latter two should be made synonyms, but that's a different issue).

Additionally `[scheme]` and `[clojure]` should also be lang-lisp and `[ml]` should be lang-ml.

I also recommend setting `[j]`, `[k]` and `[apl]` to null because those languages look horrible with default highlighting.

Answer (score 4):

```
[node.js] = lang-js
```

See, for example, [How to make an HTTP POST request in node.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6158933/http-post-request-in-node-js), which is tagged [node.js](/questions/tagged/node.js) but not [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript) and gets no highlighting.

Comment: Good catch. Never noticed that.

Answer (score 3):

I have a question about this statement:

> If a question has two tags that both define specific languages, it uses default and lets prettify infer as it always has.

So does that means that, for instance, I have two tags that are linked to the same specific language, say `[tagA] -> lang-a` and `[tagA-v3] -> lang-a`, does it fulfill the above condition, triggering default mode? Won't that be counter-productive?

If the above does **not** happen (ie. Default mode only gets triggered when two different languages are implied by the tags), then shouldn't we link libraries written in a specific language to that language? jQuery -> JavaScript comes to mind of course, but there certainly are many others. I'm asking this because there are quite a number of questions tagged [jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery) but not [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript).

---

Also, it appears as there's no such thing as `lang-as` for ActionScript. The [actionscript](/questions/tagged/actionscript) tag is currently linked to `[lang-js]`, which may or may not highlight correctly, since the two languages are based off different versions of the ECMAScript specifications.

Comment: questions tagged [jquery] tend to have a lot of html and other syntax-highlightable cruft in them. If we force a language this means every jquery question with a HTML snippet in it will NOT syntax highlight that HTML snippet.

Comment: @JeffAtwood I see. Thanks for the clarification

Comment: But, @Jeff, wouldn't the same apply to `javascript` itself? Currently that tag *does* set a specific language and hence currently requires the `html` tag to avoid HTML erroneously being highlighted as JavaScript. (See link with screen capture I added to [Shadow Wizard's answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/72082/changes-to-syntax-highlighting/72408#72408).)

Answer (score 3):

- `[sqlalchemy]` = `lang-py`
- `[webpy]` = `lang-py`
- `[cherrypy]` = `lang-py`
- `[py2exe]` = `default`
- `[beautifulsoup]` = `lang-py` or `default` as it *might* have some HTML
- `[numpy]` = `lang-py`
- `[wxpython]` = `default` (it could be XML as well)
- `[boo]` = `lang-py` (it's not the same language, but it's close enough. Only thing, there are not too many questions.)
- `[scriptaculous]` = `lang-js`
- `[turbogears]` = `lang-py`

Comment: dispute sql alchemy, and hinting it to python would break an sql queries posted as part of the question

Comment: before I take action on any of these I'd like to see specific examples of where a question *with these tags* has bad syntax highlighting

Comment: @Jeff Atwood - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4116658/ is tagged [numpy], and has no highlighting.

Answer (score 3):

Jeff, I wonder if it would be possible to have an unobtrusive display of the language which has been chosen? That would help get the tags right.

I am concerned that people will choose the tags based on the language. As I have stated before, a question should not be tagged "C#" simply because that's the language being used.

Comment: at the very least initially show the unobtrusive display, with a reminder to reevaluate in 6-8 weeks ;)

Answer (score 3):

Those tags needs *default* syntax highlighting, not *null* (also not *xml* nor *java*). They contain posts with a mix of Java code and XML-like markup. Both needs to be highlighted as nicely as it did before this change.

[jsf](/questions/tagged/jsf), [jsf-2.0](/questions/tagged/jsf-2.0), [jsp](/questions/tagged/jsp), [servlets](/questions/tagged/servlets), [servlet-filters](/questions/tagged/servlet-filters), [jstl](/questions/tagged/jstl) and [el](/questions/tagged/el).

Answer (score 2):

is there a, or do we have a need for, a `[lang-pseudo]` for when you're trying to explain something in pseudocode? (often for *my* needs `[lang-c]` would be fine `;]` )

Also, does this say what happens to *answers* formatting? What if I'm discussing `[asp.net]` with someone and the question is tagged `c#` but they really need to update the `aspx` instead of the `cs` and so I put some HTML in my answer in the codeblock, then how does it filter that my code is HTML and not C#?

Am I overthinking this?

Comment: There are now [language hints for syntax highlighting](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#syntax-highlighting). For example, to highlight HTML on a post that's otherwise tagged for C#, put `<!-- language: html -->` before your code block.

Answer (score 2):

None of the shell scripting languages have highlighting anymore

```
[bash] = lang-bsh
[shell] = lang-sh
[sh] = lang-sh
[csh] = lang-csh
[awk] = default
```

Comment: There is scripting language BeanShell, which is pretty much Java code, and the interpreter is called `bsh`. Is `bsh` a common abbrev. for `bash`?

Answer (score 2):

Octave code should be highlighted like Matlab.

```
[octave] = default
```

Answer (score 2):

Well it appears the language inference has been pulling its weight thus far. There is however a minor issue here.

I experimented with the question [Webclient.UploadFile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/982299/webclient-uploadfile) which is tagged tagged `c#`, `.net`, `vb.net` and `webclient`.

When I tried answering the question with VB.NET code [which is perfectly valid based on the OP's tags] the code I entered was formatted as C#! **Quite unbelievable!**

> *Well I did not really answer the question. I wanted to test the code inference system and from the answer preview I got, it failed to infer the language properly.*

I believe including a way to explicitly state which language should be used to highlight code entered, especially on the answerer's side, would be very much appreciated.

Comment: There's a `[feature-request]` for this, go support that

Comment: @Yi Jiang: Can you please give me the link to that [feature-request] question so I go and support it?

Comment: Hmmm, it seems like I'm wrong, http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/981/syntax-highlighting-language-hints isn't the correct `[feature-request]`. In this case, it might be good to open a new question.

Answer (score 2):

There is an inconsistency between the preview and the final result with respect to multiple language blocks.

E.g: I specify a language `<!-- language: lang-cs -->` right in front of this code block:

```cs
var test = ThisIsACSharpObject;
```

Then I have some text, and then again a code-block:

```
var test2 = ThisIsAnotherCSharpObject;
```

In the preview (on Stack Overflow proper), both blocks are formatted like they should as C# code, but when I post this, only the first one is formatted right. I have to specifically add the language tag in front of all the different codeblocks for them to be rendered right after posting.

(Apparently this doesn't work on meta... I suppose the code formatting thing is not enabled here ==> I think it should be enabled, as how can we otherwise reproduce problems concerning this here?)

**Edit**: Ow hey, apparently, here on meta this has a different behavior: I never see the code formatting in the preview while editing, but after posting, it is actually formatted (wrongly in my opinion, as only the first code block is formatted right), so we can actually reproduce this problem here... as you can see.

Comment: no guarantees whatsoever that preview will match in this case

Answer (score 2):

Questions tagged [mercurial](/questions/tagged/mercurial) often mention Python code, so I propose

```
[mercurial] = lang-py
```

Answer (score 1):

I miss the old formatting, which while imperfect at least didn't suck enough for me to complain about. So here's one I'd like to see:

```
[tcl] = default
```

Comment: (Better would be if there was Tcl highlighting in prettify, but that would require real work…)

Answer (score 1):

The [linq](/questions/tagged/linq) and [linq-to](/questions/tagged/linq-to) questions that doesn't have a specific language tag should use `default` highlighting.  Maybe even all LINQ tags?

particularly:

```
[linq]             = default
[linq-to-sql]      = default
[linq-to-entities] = default
[linq-to-xml]      = default
[linq-to-objects]  = default
```

Answer (score 1):

Most of our GWT questions/answers currently show unhighlighted code.

It probably needs default highlighting, because the questions very often include a combination of Java, HTML, CSS, XML and JavaScript code blocks, without being specific questions for these tags. <sub>(Especially, GWT is not Java, it just looks like Java code, and adding a Java tag often results in answers that work in Java, but not in GWT.)</sub>

```
[gwt] = default
```

Answer (score 0):

QTP scripts are based on VBScript

```
[qtp] = lang-vb
```