# Why isn't syntax highlighting working in a question?

Tags: support, syntax-highlighting

I recently edited [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4456835/3-tables-on-ipad-with-different-data) and now the syntax highlighting is gone (actually, I don't remember if it was there to begin with).

Before clicking Save Edits, the highlighting was visible but not after the save.

What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There have been [changes made to the syntax highlighting functionality](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/72082/changes-to-syntax-highlighting) recently.  The question you linked to is not tagged with a language, so it isn't sure what to do.  You could add the [objective-c] tag if that is appropriate (seems like it would be but I did just glance at the question) and that should kick-start the syntax highlighter.

Comment: That did it, thanks.  How would one specify a language for a tag (eg. ipad) and does that require a certain rep?

Comment: @aBitObvious, read the post I linked to. (: