# My syntax highlighting stopped working on Stack Overflow

Tags: support, stack-overflow, edits, syntax-highlighting

All of a sudden, my syntax highlighting stopped working on Stack Overflow which can be seen in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4663771/wpf-4-datagrid-getting-the-row-number-into-the-rowheader/4663799#4663799). And now, even if I edit that post, try to post a question or an answer, there's no syntax highlighting. I've never seen this before, and I don't remember doing anything special when it stopped working.

How can I get it back? I'm using Internet Explorer 8.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why isn't syntax highlighting working in a question?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/72391/why-isnt-syntax-highlighting-working-in-a-question)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Syntax highlighting has recently changed to infer which highlighting mode to use based on the tags. Since the question in question isn't tagged with any programming language, it doesn't get any highlighting.

Comment: Little confused now.. How come the other answer got syntax highlighting? In the question I linked that is

Comment: Anyway, when I tried this, of course I only experimentet on questions that didn't have any programming language tag, and then I tried with asking a question myself but I didn't fill out any tags so no syntax highlighting in neither :) Still wonder about the other answer though.. bug?