# Why does the code highlighter not work with XML?

Tags: support, code-formatting, syntax-highlighting, xml

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why isn't syntax highlighting working in a question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/72391/why-isnt-syntax-highlighting-working-in-a-question)

I have formatted my block of XML wit the `{}` button, but it just won't highlight.
Is it supposed to, I thought it used to highlight the elements and attributes at least.

Here is the link to the question:

[How to make the Stand Alone Archiva distribution the ROOT application under Jetty?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5176486/)

Comment: because there is no **`xml`** tag in the post?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The post has to have at least one tag that we consider language-y for the prettifier to work.

Your post did not have any tags that meet that criteria.

Diamond moderators can change the tag behavior in this regard on the tag info page.