# Why isn't code coloured as it should be?

Tags: support, code-formatting, syntax-highlighting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why isn't syntax highlighting working in a question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/72391/why-isnt-syntax-highlighting-working-in-a-question)

I've posted [this question on Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5179692/75642) that has some C# code in it. I've indented it correctly (I'm **not** using `<pre>` tags). But the code doesn't seem to get any colours.

A bug maybe?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The syntax highlighting takes its cues from the tags used on your question. You haven't used the [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23) tag. Add it to your question and see the syntax highlighting spring to life.

Comment: Oh thanks Chris. Tag actually did it. I haven't used `PRE` because I never do. It's easier to indent. But didn't know about tag clues. :)

Comment: And what about an answer? answers doesn't have the tags how can we highlight syntax?

Comment: @Div answers take their cues from the tags on the question.