# Code not getting syntax highlighted

Tags: support, code-formatting, syntax-highlighting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why isn't syntax highlighting working in a question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/72391/why-isnt-syntax-highlighting-working-in-a-question)

For some reason, the code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10100000/753341) is not getting syntax-highlighted. Perhaps it's a problem with my browser/cache or something? Or maybe I'm doing something wrong?

If I remember correctly, usually keywords like `class` and `public` get highlighted, this isn't happening in the answer I linked.

Answer (score 12):

Syntax highlighting is dependent on the language. By default that is chosen from the tags that are on the question. However, the question doesn't have any languages tagged. So there's no syntax highlighting.

I've edited your post to manually enable C++ syntax highlighting by adding this:

```
<!-- language: lang-cpp -->
```

More Information: [Syntax highlighting language hints](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/981/syntax-highlighting-language-hints)

Comment: But that doesn't work !!!!!!!

Comment: What doesn't work? Can you link me an example where it failed?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20728859/get-users-who-liked-my-photos-with-fql

Comment: You needed a line break before that tag. Fixed it for you. :)

Comment: Oh before, damn I searched everywhere and I couldn't figure it out and it pissed me off, at least now I know :) thanks a lot!

Comment: Should mark this as accepted.

Comment: Or simply: `<!-- language: go -->`