# Voting system for syntax highlighting

Tags: feature-request, voting, syntax-highlighting

**Syntax highlighting is a really great feature**, often debated on meta :).

Some edge corner languages or tags have a "poor" representation, due to an incomplete (and of course uncompletable) matrix relation between code and right highlithing.
The [only global post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/72082/changes-to-syntax-highlighting) I founded on this topic is now closed.

Every time we ask about interface modification (e.g. [Adding syntax highlighting item in the editing toolbar](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/137680/adding-syntax-highlighting-item-in-the-editing-toolbar) but many time over many posts), I read "Trust in automatic detection". I don't, even a really great job was accomplished yet (at least for the 40th and most useful tags ;)).

As I said, sometimes, for some extra languages / tags, it's not implemented, or not easy to such a job.

**So, why not use a voting system, maybe like moderators elections,** in order to help Mike Samuel and Jeff Atwood (if I'm not mistaken) in their job to assign a tag / a language to a syntax highlithing.

It may not be automatic, but whan a language as reached xx upvotes (lets say 150 ?), it can be consider as trustable.

Feel free to suggest any other idea, (in way of voting, vote limit, ...)

*PS : I really don't want to my request be misunderstood. Syntax highlighting is a really great functionnality, and automatic detection too. Thanks for all work already done.*

EDIT

Voting system for tag synonyms is indeed quite closer from what I suggests.
Thanks Flexo

Comment: Your proposal sounds more like the tag synonomizing process than moderator elections. I think doing it like tag synonyms might make sense, but it's a trivial action and rarely performed.

Comment: You're right ! It's quite closer than tag synonym !

Comment: Assigning syntax highlighting to tags is something all moderators and developers can do.

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn > Really ? How ?