# Enable Syntax Highlighting to code blocks on Programmers.SE

Tags: feature-request, syntax-highlighting, software-engineering-se

We have a lot of code on PSE and we will have more when some questions were migrated from SO to P.SE.

[See the post on M.P.SE](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/308/bring-syntax-highlighting-to-code-blocks-here-on-p-se)

Comment: Are you sure that [adding a language tag](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/72082/changes-to-syntax-highlighting) to a question doesn't do the trick? Ah, I guess [it does not](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/34270/best-methods-for-lazy-initialization-with-properties) but haven't checked many examples. (If it does, then you'd need to wait for hinting to get specific highlighting per answer.)

Comment: @Arjan [yes, it's definitely disabled there](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/87632/is-language-lang-blah-deployed-and-supposed-to-work-on-se-sites-such-as)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[This has been completed.](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/308/bring-syntax-highlighting-to-code-blocks-here-on-p-se)

(Maybe an up vote can get this off of my unanswered [softwareengineering-se](/questions/tagged/softwareengineering-se) list.)