# Is <!-- language: lang-blah --> deployed and supposed to work on SE sites such as Programmers?

Tags: support, syntax-highlighting

I've tried it, but it has no effect on Programmers.SE, even though it seems to work here on meta.

I see it's been only about 6 weeks [since this feature was implemented](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/63800/interface-options-for-specifying-language-prettify/81970#81970) — does it usually take longer than this to make it to other sites?

Comment: Which post on programmers.SE have you tried?

Comment: Link, or it didn't happen.

Comment: ok, should be this one - http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/68876/a-combined-if-switch-statement-syntax-with-exception-handling-for-a-c-inspired-l

Comment: I think only SO, Code Golf and Code Review have syntax highlighting. You shouldn't normally be posting code on Programmers. If your post has got real code in it then it's a prime candidate for migration to SO.

Comment: @YOU I didn't include the tags in that question, no. I only used the Preview to test this out, on a new "Ask Question" post.

Comment: See also: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/72797/enable-syntax-highlighting-to-code-blocks-on-programmers-se

Comment: @ChrisF: Add tex.sx to that list.

Comment: @romkyns: [Preview only just got support for this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/89592/implement-e-g-language-lang-css-in-preview), though, so a preview you did in mid-April doesn't actually reveal anything about whether programmers.SE had this enabled...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As [ChrisF](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/59303/chrisf) pointed out, only a very few of our sites have syntax highlighting enabled.

Syntax highlighting isn't enabled on Programmers, so naturally the syntax highlighting hints don't do anything.

Comment: that's odd. Why would they not have syntax highlighting enabled?

Comment: @Earlz I think it's probably a very SO-esque decision that is said to shape the community through various annoying features. It's annoying, but I can't claim to have evidence that it doesn't work...

Comment: @Earlz - because you're not supposed to post big chunks of code there.  StackOverflow and CodeReview both have it enabled, and a question with non-trivial code is almost certainly a better fit for one of them.

Comment: If it's to be disabled, then it's disabled rather badly: it's still enabled in the edit preview, and I'm left wondering where the heck it went after I posted :)

Comment: @romkyns: In the previewer it's a mess anyway. There often the _default_ highlighting is used; then in the final post you can have a _different_ highlighting. (That's how things are on tex.sx.)