# Implement (e.g.) <!-- language: lang-css --> in preview

Tags: bug, status-completed, markdown-preview, syntax-highlighting

Okay, so we've got [Interface options for specifying language prettify](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/63800/interface-options-for-specifying-language-prettify/81970#81970) implemented now, which is fantastic!

There's a little bitty problem, though: As it stands, this doesn't work right in previews.

For example, the preview for the text:

```
<!-- language: lang-css -->

     div#ads {
         display: none
     }
```

renders as if it were

```
<!-- language: lang-sh -->

     div#ads {
         display: none
     }
```

That is, instead of

```css
 div#ads {
     display: none
 }
```

it renders as

```sh
 div#ads {
     display: none
 }
```

It would be really nice if this would be fixed, so we could make sure we were doing things right *before* hitting "post". (I'm also not sure if the tag-based defaults are honored in the preview, which would also be quite helpful for reasons which should be obvious.)

Comment: I think the wording of this request should be generalized for any language hints.  The problem is that it doesn't apply the hints in the editor preview, what is applied is determined by the language detector (as if it were lang-default).  Is this what you guys are planning on doing @balpha?  Applying the hints in the editor preview?

Comment: @Jeff Yes -- that's what the request is about. CSS is just an example.

Comment: Most of this is done (will probably be deployed soon); only inferring the default highlighting when you change the question's tags isn't done yet.

Comment: @balpha:  I was under the impression preview didn't work and was frankly shocked today when it did!

Comment: I did find one "bug" though.  In preview, it looks correct if there is no blank line between the language hint line and the first line of code.  But after hitting submit all the code is not code.  To fix the blank line must be inserted.

Comment: @Rick: oh, yeah, I saw that even before this was implemented... maybe they ought to have written the Markdown renderer in Wasabi (so that the same code could be used for client and server) ;-P

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Most of this has been done for a while now; the only thing missing was inferring the highlighting language when you're writing/editing a question and editing its tags.

This final part will be working after the next build.