# Feature concept: Tagging answers

Tags: feature-request

We tag questions, such as "Why does my PHP goof up?", but if I'm searching for problems caused by "Problems caused by mixed quotes" (for example), it's not an easy way to search backwards.

So I suggest we allow for answer authors to tag their questions so we can think about things jeopard style as well as the normal way.

Example question:
[IE8 ignores jQuery UI 'dialog' minHeight and height settings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4519666/ie8-ignores-jquery-ui-dialog-minheight-and-height-settings)

Question tags: `javascript jquery jquery-ui` as these tags are related to the **question**

Answer **could have been** tagged: `Doctype` as the solution has nothing to do with JS, but the problem caused by that JS solution is related to Doctype, Dom, Rendering, etc...

Should the question be re-tagged doc-type? No, that doesn't make any sense, he's asking about a problem he had making the jQueryUI working.

Comment: As an aside: that *might* also help with syntax highlighting, which [currently uses the question tags](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/72082/changes-to-syntax-highlighting) to see what language to assume.

Comment: Did you mean tag their answers?

Comment: Edited my answer, and I still think you have a typo in your question.

Comment: I think you're confusing keyword search with tag-based categorization. You should stop doing that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Answers inherit the tags from the questions.  If an answer doesn't match at least one of the tags in the question, it may be an indication that it doesn't belong there.

EDIT (to answer the edit in the question):

If the answer that answers the question needs a different tag, then I retag the question.  I do this all the time on Excel questions that are tagged worksheet-function, but the answer ends up being VBA (and vice-versa).  When all is said and done the tagging on the question should reflect reality.

Having said that I can see where sometimes tagging on the answer might be something to look into, but I see it as a pretty rare occurence.  Maybe if there were lots of questions in the correct tags, and the one outlier that might need a different tag, but again, that's usually an indicator that the answer didn't fit the question.  On the question you linked to, I'd just edit in the `Doctype` tag.

Comment: Updated question to add more detail to the concept.

Comment: Q: "How do I foo in bar?" tags: foo, bar A: "By using baz" A: "by using quux"- no compelling reason to tag the question with baz or quux.

Answer (score 3):

I also think answer tagging might improve the community.

Example question: [Returning data from ajax results in strange object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12660596/returning-data-from-ajax-results-in-strange-object/12660611#comment17080928_12660611).

This question very apparently deals with misunderstanding of control flow in asynchronous operations, but it is very hard to find one of the *many* duplicate questions that deal with this issue, as they understandably never refer to the actual cause of the problem (since they also misunderstand the problem), and it is not trivial to figure out a search query that would describe the problem without refering to the cause.

Many questions (even non-duplicates) have common underlying root causes, which could be tagged on the answers. I don't believe such tagging belongs on the questions themselves, mostly because it could lead to retag struggles if multiple people have different opinions on what the root cause is.

Answer (score 3):

I agree that there is a problem.  The question title and tags are written from the perspective of someone who doesn't understand the problem.  I believe that the OP might very well use a different title and tags once they understand the answer.