# Something in the page source is keeping the code from formatting properly

Tags: support

When I edit my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4597317/problem-with-mef-exportfactoryt-call-dispose-method/4597416#4597416), the code will format properly - i.e. colored text, etc. However, when I save the edit, the formating goes away. The OP's and my answer just look like blocked text. Is there a bug, or is there a character that is keeping the formatting from working?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/72082/changes-to-syntax-highlighting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDITED** removed the unnecessary copy of his edits where I was researching the issue. View edits on this question to see them. I believe the actual problem is below.

Actually I think I see the problem. The question didn't have a .NET type tag on it, so it didn't colorize per .NET rules and MichaelMyers is right about what the problem is. I presume this is C#?