# Advanced privileges with quite low reputation

Tags: support, reputation, privileges

Today I got up and found myself able to edit other peoples questions and answers:

[image: an-answer]

with the following quite low reputation and restricted privileges:

[image: privileges]

I'm happy you respect and trust me, but I'm trying to be as honest as possible; this is a bug.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[It's a part of the new development they're doing](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/74447/allow-low-rep-users-to-suggest-edits). Apparently it's being turned on for a day, disabled, reviewed, improved, repeat, rinse until profit is achieved.

Answer (score 5):

This is *not* a bug. The team is currently conducting tests for a new feature that allows new and anonymous users to make edits to the posts pending these changes been reviewed by a high-rep user. They have been turning this feature on for several hours at a time. There have already been several sessions of these, as announced in the MSO Chatroom - see these conversation for instance:

> http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89/conversation/testing-session-3-or-4-or-something
>   http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89/conversation/testing-testing-1-2-3
>   http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89/conversation/testing-session-3-and-results

Comment: (The conversations carry a lot of other ongoing conversations, but... you get the point)

Comment: Indeed, I didn't notice any news on these events.

Comment: @YasirArsanukaev Well, these are only tests. There probably *will* be an announcement when the thing actually launches