# Is it possible to raise attention to argumentative / subjective / poorly formed posts as a basic user?

Tags: feature-request

I have had a quick look around Meta and can't find an answer.

What i'm wondering is before I have the reputation to actually vote to close a question for certain reasons. Can I at least help out by flagging the post in a way to alert other higher reputation users to have a look at it and cast their vote?

The 'flag' feature on a post is a little too harsh as I assume this flags it for moderators rather than other members.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a low-rep user, you have two options:

- **[Edit](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/74447/allow-low-rep-users-to-suggest-edits)** the post to bring it up to par.  Your edit will be placed in the edit queue, and users with edit privileges can approve the edit. You gain **+2** reputation for an approved edit.
- If the post is actually a problem post, **flagging it** is the right thing to do.  You even have the same options under "It doesn't belong here" as users with close votes do.  It's not too harsh since a moderator will take care of it in whatever manner is most appropriate.  For flagged posts on which the moderator takes action, you even gain [increased flag weight](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/80170/what-is-flag-weight) to gain more flags per day.

Comment: Thanks Renesis, I didn't notice those other options. I'm glad I can take a more active role in the community now :)