# Reject an already-approved suggested edit when rolling it back

Tags: feature-request, edits, suggested-edits, rejected-edits, rollbacks

The content of this post has been sanitized in response to anonymous feedback that the formatting was making it completely unreadable by assistive technology (AT). I strongly value making content accessible over proving a point against users who willfully contribute to making content inaccessible. [Read this post as it was originally intended to be read, at your own peril.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/revisions/137755/1)

---

I just had to roll back about a dozen incorrect suggested edits that were approved, because all they did was litter backticks all over random words and phrases and calling it improved formatting.

This is just one of the less exciting cleanup tasks I've taken it upon myself to do, as these edits are not only rampantly suggested, but also rampantly approved, obviously by the same people who think it is for whatever reason OK to mark keywords and other random things with backticks.

The fact that I'm rolling these edits back means that these edits shouldn't have been approved in the first place. Since rejecting a suggested edit denies the editor of the +2 rep bonus that would otherwise be awarded when the edit is approved, I propose that rolling such an edit back do two things:

1. Mark the edit as rejected instead of approved, either by Community♦ or the user performing the rollback, preferably with the invalid edit reason if not one of the user's choosing.
2. Revoke the +2 rep bonus that was awarded when the edit was approved, if applicable.

Comment: My eyes hate you now, well done.

Comment: This is a great idea, and would make it much easier to get those users edit-banned

Comment: I `like` this idea.

Comment: Frankly, I think those approving such crap are the _actual_ problem. We've all made pointless edits at first, at least I know I did, and I had absolutely no clue I was doing something wrong while my edits were getting approved.

Comment: Limiting it to zee mods would probably be the safest bet; but that's a sort of heavy-handed solution.

Comment: @jadarnel27 Yes, give more guns to the criminally insane, good plan ;)

Comment: @YannisRizos I hate it when I run out of comment upvotes.

Comment: While I agree with the *vast* majority of the corrections you made to those posts, I do think that putting backticks around programming language keywords, class names, and function names is okay.  I'd approve edits where those were the only changes made.  (That's not the case here, I'm just trying to find where the line is.)

Comment: @Bill the Lizard: I usually keep those, but in this case I was too annoyed and lazy to care.

Comment: Ah okay, just checking.  I did see a couple of class names that got changed, but they were definitely lost in the noise of many other pointless changes.  Carry on.  :)

Comment: @YannisRizos Right, this is just a symptom.  The real issue is that apparently some people mindlessly accept edits, so let's work on stopping that from happening.

Comment: Avoiding abuse: make it mod only? Mass rollbacks sounds like a mod thing anyway.

Comment: Many of those suggested edits were quite old. Should time between edit and rollback matter too? (This user has been doing this from September 2011 until a month ago, though in fact some suggested were rejected with *"Please don't wrap code tags around things that are not code"* which should have made that user aware.)

Comment: And maybe: 3. Somehow notify the approvers too?

Comment: @Arjan: Which reminds me of http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/120624/decision-on-rejected-edits-should-be-displayed-as-a-notification-to-the-editor

Comment: Related: [Please facilitate undoing the harm from bad suggested edits](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/122038) [What can we do to stop bad edits getting accepted?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/137784)

Comment: +1 and give the user who did the excess back ticks -2 rep for making me spend more money at the optometrist.

Comment: @sixlettervariables: The backticks on this question? That would be me.

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn: -2 for funsies. My suggestion would be ordered list item #3.

Comment: We needs this so badly. Still finding accounts that are farming rep by spamming the site with bad edits.

Comment: I'm glad I'm not the only one seeing this, but for God's sake, make it stop! Maybe we need to raise the rep bar for people to approve edits.

Comment: Since Unicorns are frequently Rampant, this somehow seems like poetic justice.

Comment: Another user with the `random` backticks: http://stackoverflow.com/users/1455421/shekhar-chikara?tab=activity&sort=suggestions. But not as bad since some of the things really are code, and he also fixes misspellings.

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/898310

Comment: @BradMace - I've seen people with 60K+ rep approve the most atrocious edits.  It'd be a first for SO, but I think users should have to be able to pass a test to be able to approve edits.  You can't identify bad edits?  Then you don't get to approve them.

Comment: @LittleBobbyTables: That would be awesome. There's the question of how exactly we're going to implement such a test, of course... but with such a smart team of developers here I'm sure they'll figure something out.

Comment: And if you think this is only a problem with users with < 2k rep... I don't even know if this is a new low or a new, er, high... http://stackoverflow.com/posts/13248493/revisions (see revision 2)

Comment: As an aside almost all rep (except I think bounties). can be reversed via unaccepting, unvoting, post deletion, user deletion, or sock puppet detection. Why are suggested edits so unimpeachable.

Comment: If I edit this post to remove all the unnecessary `backticks`, will that be rejected?

Comment: @Aditya: [Here's your answer.](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/13987)

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn: Hehe... I had almost given up the hope of a reply from you... :)

Comment: @Aditya As long as you give the reason "Weakened formatting", I think you are guaranteed for approval!

Comment: Can I just paste a link to this post as a custom suggested edit rejection reason?

Comment: @apaul34208: Sure, although this may be a better link as my question isn't really about the nature of the edit: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135112/inline-code-spans-should-not-be-used-for-emphasis-right

Comment: I vote this is tagged as featured so people can be reminded how annoying it is... I've been seeing a bunch of these lately.

Comment: @WendiKidd: Unfortunately this may not be the right question for it as it's really about reverting suggested edits, with formatting abuse being merely an example of the kind of edit that should be reverted.

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn Yeah, I meant edits; I've been seeing a bunch of people approving suggested edits that only add backticks in random places. But if you don't think it will help then I bow to your experience in the matter :)

Comment: Some edits shouldn't earn rep.  If I make a spelling error, and then correct it, should I really get two points for THAT?  But can AI tell the difference?

Comment: @WGroleau - If you are editing your own post, it applies immediately, i.e. the system recognises that you are editing your own post and it isn't put in the review queue. This discussion is about users who edit *other people's* posts, and the people who review and approve them.

Comment: @Robotnik: that makes sense, but I still got two (silly) points for fixing my own typo.

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/15264636) is one of those edits you're mentioning. I had to go and edit it back once it got approved to remove those harmful changes (I couldn't even rollback since another user made a useful edit in between). I agree that those kinds of edits are really annoying. Besides this user has earned more than 100 reputation for suggesting edits like those. At least in this case the question got deleted so the user lost his 2 reputation, which is unfortunately not always the case. (Also +1 for imitating those bad edits in your question).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Could authors overturn recent community review decisions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/178340/could-authors-overturn-recent-community-review-decisions)

Answer (score 187):

[You](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/137537/boltclocks-a-unicorn) make a **very** good point about [edits](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit) getting

> not only rampantly suggested, but also rampantly approved

but [I](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/170332/dennis) think that [*your*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/137537/boltclocks-a-unicorn) idea of

> 1. Mark[ing] the edit as rejected [...]
> 2. Revok[ing] the +2 rep bonus [...]

doesn't address

## the real problem

which is not the **low reputation users** [*suggesting*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/74447/allow-low-rep-users-to-suggest-edits) bad [edits](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit), but the **high reputation users** [*approving*](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/approve-tag-wiki-edits) them.

---

This is why [I](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/170332/dennis) came up with the following

## COUNTER PROPOSAL

which consists in

- **sending a notification** to a user if a [suggested edit](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/74447/allow-low-rep-users-to-suggest-edits) that has been [*approved*](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/approve-tag-wiki-edits) *by them* (or a **certain number** of edits) get [rolled back](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17038/what-is-a-rollback).
- **temporarily suspending** the [approving privileges](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/approve-tag-wiki-edits) of a user if **too many** of their [approved edits](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/approve-tag-wiki-edits) have been [rolled back](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17038/what-is-a-rollback).

Comment: The general idea on Stack Exchange is not sending notifications for something negative users did; notifications should always be for something positive.

Comment: @kiamlaluno: That's true, but is that a good thing? This idea apart, if I'm doing something that will result in a suspension if repeated, I'd certainly prefer to be notified.

Comment: Another recent of blind approval: http://stackoverflow.com/review-beta/suggested-edits/763823

Comment: @random: Markdown syntax errors and lack of proper capitalization aside, *helle all*? Seriously??? That does it. This thing needs a bounty.

Comment: I see these at least once a week on the R tag.  Just now I had to roll this one back: http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/3896505  Everything it changes about the question is invalid:  It reintroduces "R" in the title which is redundant, while also adding "Statistics" to the title of a question that has nothing to do with statistics.  If that's not enough, it adds the "printing" tag, which doesn't seem to be helpful at all.  How about revoking the +2 edit bonus if the question is rolled back within a certain period of time?

Comment: I just tried to reject an edit where someone removed alternative text to an image.  Unfortunately it got approved out from under me in less than 30 seconds.  Perhaps some folks aren't taking the time required to actually read what they're approving?

Answer (score 60):

The content of this post has been sanitized in response to anonymous feedback that the formatting was making it completely unreadable by assistive technology (AT). I strongly value making content accessible over proving a point against users who willfully contribute to making content inaccessible. [Read this post as it was originally intended to be read, at your own peril.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/revisions/137786/1)

---

Some caveats and other concerns:

- As people blindly approve these edits, people may just as blindly roll them back. In a more serious case, one could also use one's edit privileges to serially roll back a user's suggested edits, thereby making it basically a different flavor of revenge downvoting — and one much harder to reverse. I don't like the sound of that...
- If we limit who can perform such rollbacks, who exactly do we limit it to? Users of a certain reputation level? Moderators? Someone else?
- What about the users who are approving these edits? How do we address them?

In fact, now that I think about it, I should agree that the problem probably lies in these users who are blindly approving these edits in the first place, more so than the edits themselves which could have been rejected just as easily.

Comment: Made this an `answer` so the `question` doesn't look like it's `contradicting itself`.

Comment: I'm confused. What's bad about undoing vandalism?

Comment: @bemace: If the +2 rep from approving an edit was docked, one could theoretically target someone's good edits by rolling them all back. In that case, the vandalism lies in rolling back the good edits. Not to mention lost rep that was actually gained fairly.

Comment: Ah, I see what you were saying. Hopefully the suspicious voting detector could be applied to this as well though.

Comment: Isn't this what **flagging** is for?  I mean if a couple other high-rep mods notice what's happening, I would think it'd be curtains for the perpetrator...

Comment: I still think it should be `possible` to `undo` the +2 rep gained if a user gained `a lot` of rep by proposing `bad edits` that are `approved` by `bad reviewers`. This [happened recently](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260042/1313143). With sufficient `control` (e.g. only `mods` can do it) in place, this could work out `fine`, surely?

Comment: You `could` do so that if a `normal` 2K user rolls `back`, it has no `more` effect than it currently `has`, and if a `moderator` or a very `high-reputation` user rolls back, it can `have` the effects that you `suggested`.

Answer (score 38):

I disagree. The fact that **2** reviewers have voted to approve the edit *should* (note, *should*) indicate that the edit is acceptable.

It would be `wrong` for *one* user (note, I accept it's different for you as a moderator) to be able to override the decision of those two users, and to undermine them by rolling back the edit.

What I propose instead is;

1. Rather than simply needing two approval votes to be approved, an edit is only accepted if the number of approval votes is **`at-least`** 2 greater than the number of rejection votes.

   e.g, if one user rejects the edit, the edit *then* needs 3 approval votes.

   This gets more pairs of eyes on the controversial edits to make sure the right decision is made.
2. Better information to the editors about what should be accepted. This problem is *not* restricted to backticks, nor is it restricted to approvals-that-shouldn't-have-been. I see rejected edits that *should* have been approved and vice-versa `all` the time.

Comment: Note that 2 reviewers is only true for Stack Overflow.

Comment: @YannisRizos: Indeed, but I'd be more than annoyed if someone started adding code-tags to random words on [Bicycles](http://bicycles.stackexchange.com).

Comment: People who do it thinking it's a good way to emphasize, will do it regardless if they are on Bicycles, or, don't know, Biblical Hermeneutics, Gaming, etc. But I'm more thinking of Programmers, were edits are approved by one user _and_ we have valid uses for code blocks.

Comment: @YannisRizos: I guess the easiest thing to do there would be to increase the number of votes needed for it to be approved?

Comment: I agree that the approvers are a problem, but getting more eyes isn't realistic when we're struggling to keep up with the queue.

Comment: You all realize backticks were just an `example` of `one kind` of bad edit, right?

Comment: @Gilles: If it's any consolation, controversial edits are only a small percentage (6.4%, based on last months #) of the total.

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn You realize that focusing on the tree and completely ignoring the forest is what MSO is about, right? ;P

Comment: @BoltClocksaUnicorn: Indeed. I was just **`re-enforcing`** the point.

Comment: @Matt I wonder how many edits were unanimously wrongly rejected/approved. I should go through a statistical sample. When I have the time, in six to eight eons.

Comment: @Yannis Rizos: I knew that. I was just performing a counter-productive sanity check on the insane people of Meta.

Comment: *"The fact that 2 reviewers have voted to approve the edit should (note, should) indicate that the edit is acceptable."* Or it could indicate 2 reviewers have no clue what they're doing and/or are gaming for badges and should be banned from accepting edits.

Comment: What what might be the impact if after an approval, there were a limited amount of time during which reject votes could still affect the result?

Comment: I agree, it may lead to abuse. My suggestion is to implement this feature request only for rollbacks made my the OP or a moderator (who still have a binding vote when reviewing suggested edits), and leave rollbacks as they are for normal 2K users.

Answer (score 23):

Instead of concentrating on rollbacks reversing the rep gains from edits that have already been made (which I agree pretty much needs to be done by diamond moderators; it would be silly to require 3 reject votes in the suggested edits queue by ordinary users to block an edit, but then allow a single non-mod to overrule the approve votes), the system should concentrate on weeding out the reviewers who approve these in the first place.

How? Audits. We've all seen audits designed to catch people who aren't paying attention at all and who won't notice blatant vandalism. We also need audits that are clearly under the "too minor" category. Throw purported edits where some backticks are placed around a couple of words into the audits. Include some fixes to a single misspelled word. These problems will disappear quite quickly.

Comment: Are you suggesting an incentive for me to NOT fix my own typos?

Comment: No, I'm suggesting that if you're editing a post and you make typos, it shouldn't be accepted in the first place, and once we can all the roboreviewers it wouldn't be.

Comment: Bear with me while I clarify to the extreme: it's okay for me to correct typos in my own posts, but not in someone else's posts?

Answer (score 20):

Instead of introducing a new feature, I think it is better to educate both the editor and the reviewer - for the first time they gain privilege to edit/review. I doubt people check meta frequently, and I doubt people know what to check for when they edit/review for the first time.

We can give specific example of how to transform a badly formatted post to a clean post. There are enough suggested edits on SO to pick out one example. Or we can just create an example on our own.

The guide for editor/reviewer should mention:

- Salutation
- Tagging
- Various stuffs about formatting code (indentation, syntax highlighting, `<pre>`/4-space/back-tick)
- Quoting
- Do not overuse formatting
- Substantial edit
- (Esp. tag wiki) Do not copy content.
- Visit meta site for changes in policy.

The guide should be paginated - something look like cartoon, so that reader will not be overwhelmed. Each of the page can contain a link to the relevant part in the FAQs or relevant meta question.

Answer (score 5):

Despite the fact that this is a reviewer problem, as all the other answers seem to point out against this feature, I would love to see your request implemented, given the sheer number of bad suggested edit reviewers, the inefficacy of audits (compared to the other review queues), and the effect rejection rates have on suggested edit bans (though [being able to add those manually](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/221832/moderators-should-be-able-to-manually-ban-users-from-suggesting-edits) would be fantastic too). Abuse isn’t much of a problem, either; rolling back the rollback can be taken into account, for example.

To sum up: a rollback is usually well-thought-out; it being prioritized over queue reviews is fine.