# When to designate inline snippets as code

Tags: discussion, markdown, code-formatting

As far as style goes, which is the most appropriate for stackoverflow?

1. Don't forget to change the margins.
2. Don't forget to change the `margin`s.
3. Don't forget to change the `margins`.

I prefer number 2. For a property that is a keyword as well as a normal English word—such as margin, or border—it is more ambiguous. I don't think many people would argue against "Don't forget to change the `-o-text-shadow`s"

In addition, what is the best way to treat filenames and extensions?

1. .css
2. `.css`

I ask because I use ` judiciously, but I have had them edited out of my answers.

Does it harm the readability of a post, or is it appropriate to treat any snippet of code as code—even if it is one word?

Comment: Personally, I find posts [peppered with backticks](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/137755/reject-an-already-approved-suggested-edit-when-rolling-it-back) undesirable, and would select option 1.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer your number 1. If you really want to emphasize that you're talking about the specific attributes, or if there might be some ambiguity, do something like:

> Don't forget to change the `margin` attributes.

This makes it clear what you're talking about while at the same time not `giving` the `impression` of sprinkling `random` code tags `on` English words (which is annoying).

Putting extensions in inline code blocks is fine.

Comment: After having viewed a number of suggested edits that follow the #2 syndrome, I have to agree. That, and it's a slippery slope to simply say "Don't forget to change the `margin`s.", and not to start `turning` the `sentence` into a `backtick` `pollute`d `mess`.