# What to do if an edit vandalising the original post is approved?

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits, spam, rollbacks, vandalism

Look at this [suggested Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/1030993). In this the anonymous user has added a line

> please i want to do project that going to done on reporting system so
>   help me

and also ruined the formatting of the code. Still it was approved by the community. What should be done in the cases like this?

EDIT:As suggested I have rolled back the changes, but shouldn't there be some kind of a flag or something to flag those approvers(who I think approved the post even without reading the edit).?

Comment: Oh, for the power to send those robot-approvers a piece of my mind..

Comment: Give [Reject an already-approved suggested edit when rolling it back](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/137755/reject-an-already-approved-suggested-edit-when-rolling-it-back) some love, and see [What can we do to stop bad edits getting accepted?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/137784/what-can-we-do-to-stop-bad-edits-getting-accepted).

Comment: I'm at least one of the approvers of the edit and that was a mistake.

Comment: WTF 3 approvers for such an obviously bad edit.

Comment: @CodesInChaos Yes, these are moment that I'm not proud on myself....WTF indeed...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you have over 2,000 reputation just roll it back.

If you have less then 2,000 reputation flag it for moderator attention so they can roll it back.

Comment: Ok, thanks I have rolled back the changes.

Comment: Even if you have the ability to roll the edit back, I'd still recommend flagging this, because we may want to have a conversation with the reviewers involved. Flags like this have also helped us see connections between reviewers and suggesters on at least one occasion.

Comment: @Brad, care to post that comment as an answer in [What can we do to stop bad edits getting accepted?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/137784/what-can-we-do-to-stop-bad-edits-getting-accepted) as well?

Comment: @BradLarson I have flagged the question, can't see an option to flag a suggested edit