# Reputation disappearing

Tags: support, reputation, edits

I edited three posts yesterday on stackoverflow and got +2 reputation for each. It still says so in my activity record. However when I looked again later, that reputation disappeared. Honestly, all three of the posts were pretty crappy anyway, even after my edits... I was mostly just trying to fix backticks, spelling and grammar. My reputation was at 1444 before the edits, and 1450 after.

What most likely happened? All three of the posts are still there, two of them still say they were edited last by me...

- [One post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12276880/how-to-change-delphi-xe2-default-behaviour-for-some-panes/13443984#13443984)
- [Other post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9198508/xampp-use-ip-address-rather-than-127-0-0-1-or-localhost/13444030#13444030)

What happened?

Comment: None of the edited posts were deleted, so if you lost rep it had nothing to do with those edits, it was some completely unrelated even that happened to reduce your rep by an equal an opposite amount.  This could be from deleting posts of yours with upvotes, you downvoting answers, votes of another user being reversed, older suggested edits of yours having their posts deleted, and so on (the permutations are...large, for a net reputation change of -6).

Comment: Your use of backticks isn't very appropriate for the first post.

Comment: @Servy: thanks... but there are no minuses listed (and I didn't downvote anything yesterday, anyway). I thought that might be the case but is there a way to know what it was?

Comment: @durron597 Check the "show removed posts" checkbox at the bottom of the reputation list.

Comment: Your edit of the second answer also turned the `Listen` directive into the `listen` verb, which arguably removes something from the original post.

Comment: It doesn't appear as though you lost reputation on those 2 posts.  maybe some +rep from sometime in the past had been deleted.

Comment: @durron597 See: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/137755/reject-an-already-approved-suggested-edit-when-rolling-it-back; for all that's holy, don't use backticks to add emphasis to semi-random words.

Comment: I was trying to clearly distinguish between menu options and english text. Is that wrong? I mean, the suggested edit was approved...

Comment: Unfortunately lots of bad edits get approved (the subject of a number of recent meta posts) so you can't read too much into that.

Comment: Hmm, this does look weird. Something triggered a recalculation of your rep that dropped you back from 1450 to 1444, but I'm not sure *what*.

Comment: @AnnaLear: As a moderator, are you able to see changes to my rep that I am not (but, in this case, was not on your privileged list either?)

Comment: @durron597 Basically, yes.