# Bolding of Keywords in Posts

Tags: discussion

A reviewer edited my post and made product keywords bold.  I was wondering if this was an SO  guideline (similar to the guideline of not including product names in the title) that I may have missed.  Is there something in place to bold product names of "Telerik" and "ASP.NET AJAX" (in my situation, it's referring to this: [RadMenu Finding Items Recursively By Value on Client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14326968/radmenu-finding-items-recursively-by-value-on-client)).

Comment: Related (the one I always link to when commenting that random highlighting is inappropriate): http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/137755/reject-an-already-approved-suggested-edit-when-rolling-it-back

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Personally, I reject such edits and roll them back where I see them (or edit to remove the bold if there are valuable edits that would get rolled back).

I find the arbitrary bold font scattered around the post to be irritating and makes for a less readable post.

The particular edit is just harmful - it adds nothing and actually removed a good part - the code markup around the method name.

Comment: I resisted the temptation to add bold text to your post... but just barely...

Comment: I agree; I dislike the bolded text.  Thanks.