# Using inline code formatting

Tags: discussion, edits, review, code-formatting, inline-code

Shouldn't inline formatting be used only for code? Recently a lot of people apply it to non-code blocks like:

1. Frameworks: Bootstrap, Backbone.js, AngularJS ...
2. UI elements, when a user says *logout* button
3. Console messages

These edits pass in the review. I think that's incorrect.

Comment: See [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/137755/reject-an-already-approved-suggested-edit-when-rolling-it-back).