# How can I comment to the reviewers or editors on bad edits?

Tags: discussion, edits, review, suggested-edits

I just looked at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7463074/2065121) on the edit review queue and saw that it was a pointless minor edit to a very old question and rejected as too minor. However, in the meantime, the robo-reviewers had approved it.

Ok, I went to the question and rolled back but it seems to me that the original editor was proposing a minor edit solely for the +2 rep. It will take him a long time to progress like that, but what *is* the correct action when I see this sort of thing happening? How can I comment to the approving reviewers or highlight the bad edit to the editor?

Comment: Agree that it's minor but in my opinion you shouldn't have rolled it back. The "damage" i.e. bump is already done; rolling back won't change this fact. So the reputation: he got the +2 and rolling back didn't take it away. If you see such edit still pending reject it, otherwise no need for any action. Last but not least, you will probably find [this request](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/137755/152859) interesting.

Comment: I have a different question...why is that question still open?

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd - ok, I rolled back thinking it would have an option like "the original edit was helpful/unhelpful" so I could feedback to the editor.

Comment: Indeed, rejection out of spite is immoral.

Comment: @Roger fair enough, but until that linked feature is done rolling back has no side effect.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd thanks for that linked feature request - it obviously gets my vote.

Comment: @M.NightDemonbobby Look again, it isn't.

Comment: 5 edits to a question consisting of a single line (not counting salutation)? Wow.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From my point of view, the edit was completely correct. Please look at the selected answer on a [previous related question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/2950/212576).

Also, if you look at the reviewers info on review page, you'll notice that they are not "robo-reviewers" as you like to call them.

```
Baba has approved 1778 edit suggestions and rejected 122 edit suggestions
Aquillo has approved 33 edit suggestions and rejected 4 edit suggestions
undur_gongor has approved 56 edit suggestions and rejected 23 edit suggestions
```

One of the user (**undur_gongor**) has rejected nearly half suggestions as approved. Another one (**Baba**) has nearly 125 rejections (though, compared to 1700+ approvals, it is still quite less).

Comment: PS: I think a look at [Jon Skeet's view point](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/2960/212576) wouldn't hurt either.

Comment: Ok, maybe I was harsh with the "robo-reviewers" line - having a bad day and trying to be perfect isn't always compatible with good manners. I will try to improve myself too ... your viewpoint welcome.