# How to prevent users from emphasizing text in comments as "code" instead of "emphasis"?

Tags: discussion, comments, markdown, code-formatting, inline-code

Recently I have seen several comments that use `code formatting` (with `…`) instead of *emphasis*  (with *…*) in order to format some text.

This is not correct since the text is not code and this results in text using [monospaced font](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monospaced_font), the display is not pleasing in my opinion.

Can this be prevented by displaying a warning when some text is formatted as code? It would be hard to distinguish when the usage is correct or not.

See these examples on websites unrelated to code:

> [image]

[How did my candle wax crawl up the sides of the jar?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/256674/how-did-my-candle-wax-crawl-up-the-sides-of-the-jar/256684#comment568564_256684)

> [image]

[Should I use gasoline 87, 89 or 93 on 2016 RAV4 SE](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/29953/should-i-use-gasoline-87-89-or-93-on-2016-rav4-se/29954#comment49743_29954)

Comment: They're **comments**... If it's in a question or answer, edit it out... but in comments, it's not going to hurt anything and the OP won't be able to edit it at all after five minutes. Yes, ask them not to do it in future but really, I don't think this is an issue.

Comment: @Catija `OK, I'll ignore these comments from now.`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can't really prevent that, same way we can't [prevent it in suggested edits](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/137755/reject-an-already-approved-suggested-edit-when-rolling-it-back).

For good and for bad, many users simply consider this as valid formatting, and blocking it altogether would make more harm than good.

We can, of course, post a comment reply saying something like:

> @codeabusername Inline code formatting should be used only for code, to highlight other text please surround it with `*` and `*`

However, considering the vast amount of users who do it, it will just be a drop in a vast ocean.

I'm afraid that on this one, we don't really have a choice but to accept defeat, `swallow the frog`, and move on.

[image]

Comment: What about displaying a warning to the user if backticks are used in comments on websites where code is rarely relevant? Code in backticks is relevant on SO, SU or Unix but not on Travel or Mechanics.

Comment: @A.L interesting idea, think suggested before, worth taking a look and starting a separate feature request in case it wasn't. (As this here sounds more  like an open discussion?)

Comment: @A.L remember that "backticks" != "code". Backticks give you a *preformatted* block; that doesn't have to contain code, although it is the most common use.

Comment: @ArtOfCode wrong. Unless [the official help page](http://meta.stackexchange.com/editing-help) is wrong as well, as it clearly says in the sample: "inline `code in backticks`". It should not be abused for anything else.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Do you think it's better to edit this question or open a new one (in case there is no similar question yet)?

Comment: @ShadowWizard no, I disagree. You should put code in backticks, that's certain, and that's what that page is saying. That *doesn't* preclude you from putting other things in backticks, as long as it's a reasonable use. Emphasis is not a reasonable use; things like program output (which is not code) are.

Comment: @ArtOfCode Except code or program output, what can be put into backticks?

Comment: @A.L Anything that requires a monospace font. It can be useful to put calculations in preformatted blocks, for example.

Comment: @ArtOfCode well, it's not really relevant for comments, which shouldn't contain such things... anyway guess we might disagree on what's reasonable and what isn't.

Comment: @A.L yes, as I said in the previous comment, better start a new feature request suggesting to show warning when using backticks in comments for non programming sites.