# Display a warning when backticks are used incorrectly to format text as code

Tags: feature-request, comments, markdown, code-formatting, inline-code

This is a follow-up of a [previous discussion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/279564/237701).

---

Recently I have seen several comments that use `code formatting` (with `…`) instead of *emphasis*  (with *…*) in order to format some text.

On one hand, this is not correct since the text is not code, as written in the [documentation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/editing-help#comment-formatting):

> [image]

On the other hand, as written by ArtOfCode, backticks may be used even if the text is not code:

> @A.L remember that "backticks" != "code". Backticks give you a preformatted block; that doesn't have to contain code, although it is the most common use. – [ArtOfCode](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/262823/artofcode) [23 hours ago](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/279564/how-to-prevent-users-from-emphasizing-text-in-comments-as-code-instead-of-emp#comment906129_279566)

> @A.L Anything that requires a monospace font. It can be useful to put calculations in preformatted blocks, for example. – [ArtOfCode](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/262823/artofcode) [22 hours ago](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/279564/how-to-prevent-users-from-emphasizing-text-in-comments-as-code-instead-of-emp#comment906134_279566)

**I suggest to prevent this by displaying a warning when backticks are used on websites where code is not common, in questions, answers and comments:**

> This post contain some text formatted as code, please check that the format follow the [official guidelines about code formatting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/editing-help#comment-formatting).

---

See these examples on websites unrelated to code:

> [image]

[How did my candle wax crawl up the sides of the jar?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/256674/how-did-my-candle-wax-crawl-up-the-sides-of-the-jar/256684#comment568564_256684)

> [image]

[Should I use gasoline 87, 89 or 93 on 2016 RAV4 SE](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/29953/should-i-use-gasoline-87-89-or-93-on-2016-rav4-se/29954#comment49743_29954)

Comment: Coming from a language site (where 99 % of all backticks should be asterisks), I like this. However, why only comments? This applies to questions and answers as well.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft You're right! I have updated the question. If you can provide an example of backticks in a question or answer I would be glad to add it in the question.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft because unlike questions and answers, comments can't be edited by others, so the only way to stop this is try blocking it in advance, before it's posted.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Even if the questions and answers can be edited, it would be nice to avoid these edits by alerting the users when they post.

Comment: ELL [gets](http://ell.stackexchange.com/revisions/90759/1) a [ton](http://ell.stackexchange.com/revisions/90568/1) of [these](http://ell.stackexchange.com/revisions/89755/1) in posts.

Comment: Not just ELL: ELU as well. Some is due to using four spaces to indent instead of `>`, so that formatting quirk might usefully be included.