# Inconsistent highlighting of HTML block

Tags: support, syntax-highlighting

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4656941/jquery-toggle-close-all-except-this) has this block of HTML:

```
<h4 class="toggle">Title1</h4>
<h4 class="toggle">Title2</h4>
<h4 class="toggle">Title3</h4>
<div class="container">Content1</div>
<div class="container">Content2</div>
<div class="container">Content3</div>
```

Which is rendered with these strange colors:

[image]

There's another JavaScript code block on the page. I'm not sure if the bug would show itself were that other block removed, since the highlighter isn't working during preview for me.

Comment: Related: [Shadow Wizard's answer at Changes to syntax highlighting](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/72082/changes-to-syntax-highlighting/72408#72408).

Answer (score 2):

See: [Changes to syntax highlighting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/72082/changes-to-syntax-highlighting)

All blocks use the same language (or the same default), and indeed the HTML block <s>is</s> was using JavaScript:

```
<pre class="lang-js prettyprint">
```

I've fixed it by adding the [html](/questions/tagged/html) tag, which forced all code blocks to fallback to the default highlighting:

```
<pre class="default prettyprint">
```