# How does one suggest changes to per-tag syntax highlighting?

Tags: support, status-completed, tags, syntax-highlighting

In the [question introducing language specific syntax highlighting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/72082) Jeff asks people to suggest how different tags should be highlighted.

[My suggestion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/72082/changes-to-syntax-highlighting/73852#73852) that [c++0x](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b0x) should be highlighted like [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) hasn't been implemented (although it's over a month old) as can be seen from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4589214/lambdas-cant-be-compared) which is tagged [c++0x](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b0x) and not [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b).

Is there a different mechanism to suggest changes for these rules?

Comment: Thanks @Geoff, I'm guessing this means that there is no other process.

Comment: Is there really no answer to this question?  I'd like to see the `ada` tag associated with `lang-ada`, which appears to work well when manually applied to a post