# HTML markup blocks don't highlight as HTML in [css] questions automatically

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, syntax-highlighting

Code blocks predominantly containing HTML are always highlighted as CSS the moment a question bears the [css](/questions/tagged/css) tag, *regardless of whether or not the* [html](/questions/tagged/html) *tag is present.* I always need to force HTML blocks in [css](/questions/tagged/css) questions and their answers to highlight correctly using the

```html
<!-- language: lang-html -->
```

or

```html
<!-- language-all: lang-html -->
```

hints.

**EDIT:** I've found that including the [xhtml](/questions/tagged/xhtml) tag also causes (X?)HTML to be correctly highlighted without the need for hints (see for example [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5455768/browsers-think-div-not-ending)), but I don't think I should need to add/replace tags to fix this kind of problem.

IME, it's highly unlikely that a code block starting with a `<` character is CSS, as [`<` isn't seen anywhere in CSS code](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-syntax) except within strings and comments. Even if, in a block, CSS is embedded within HTML `<style>` tags, as long as I make that block highlight as HTML, the content of the `<style>` tags also correctly highlights as CSS anyway:

```html
<style type="text/css">
/* This is CSS */
.example {
    color: red;
}
</style>
<!-- This is HTML -->
<p class="example">See? Even meta does it right.</p>
```

The only corner case I can think of is when HTML and CSS are trapped in a single code block like this without any `<style>` tags:

```css
<p class="example">HTML paragraph.</p>

.example {
    color: red;
}
```

Other than that, if the syntax highlighter can already sniff HTML/XML blocks in other questions (based in part on the `<` character), what stops it from doing so for [css](/questions/tagged/css) questions?

Comment: Yeah, this is a bit annoying. I can never be bothered to fix it. Can [you fix](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/6311792/revisions) my other 1000 answers? :)

Comment: @thirtydot: Now that you ask... no. /trollface

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Irrelevant -- the actual prettify styles for the tags are:

- [css](/questions/tagged/css) -- lang-css
- [html](/questions/tagged/html) -- lang-default

See the rules here:

[Changes to syntax highlighting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/72082/changes-to-syntax-highlighting)

> 1. If a question has no tags with a default or specific language hint, no syntax highlighting will be performed.
> 2. If a question has at most one tag with a specific language hint, plus any number of default or null hints, then syntax highlighting will be performed only for that specific language.
> 3. If a question has two tags that both define specific languages, it uses default and lets prettify infer as it always has.
> 4. As long as a question has one or more tags with default language hints, but none with a specific language hint, it uses default and let prettify infer as it always has.

Comment: Does this mean [html] has a default hint to stop prettify from going default on questions with other specific tags?

Comment: did you read the above list? pay special attention to #2.

Comment: I did, but my next question is why [html] uses the default hint.