# What happened to the syntax highlighting here on meta?

Tags: bug, status-completed, syntax-highlighting

I can understand there not being any highlighting by default, but it's difficult to demonstrate problems with the highlighting here (besides this one, obviously) when you can't even do it by [specific request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/63800/interface-options-for-specifying-language-prettify).

For example, this source:

```
<!-- language: lang-c -->

    #include <stdio.h>

    main(int argc, char *argv[])
    {
        printf("Hello, World!\n");
    }
```

currently produces this rendering:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    printf("Hello, World!\n");
}
```

which is utterly lacking in color, and does not bear the "lang-c" class.

Comment: Syntax highlighting is enabled globally on a per-site basis, and is apparently not on here. I'm going to interpret this as a "please turn on syntax highlighting on meta" request and not answer

Comment: I *was* actually wondering when/how it got turned off, and was I just blind that I couldn't find the discussion?

Comment: Was it actually ever on? I don't recall

Comment: I don't see why meta would ever need syntax highlighting, so my guess is that it was never enabled... except perhaps by mistake?

Comment: It was on when http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/81970/145828 was last edited

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Meta never had code highlighting explicitly enabled, and in September we changed the default value of that setting from true to false, at which point syntax highlighting thus disappeared from Meta. Considering that it took four months for this to be noticed, it doesn't seem to have been a huge issue, but I agree that there are cases where it's helpful here, so I've turned it on.

Comment: How strange... it has *always* worked for me in this question of mine: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/99725/html-markup-blocks-dont-highlight-as-html-in-css-questions-automatically

Comment: If a highlighting language was specified *on submission*, it continued to work. Had someone edited that question between September and today, the newly rendered version wouldn't have been highlighted.

Comment: That makes sense. Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: @balpha It would be nice if it could be turned on on http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com too, see [this feature request](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/873/there-is-no-syntax-highlighting-on-meta)