# Hash (#) Character Causing Unwanted Code Grey-out

Tags: feature-request, code-formatting, syntax-highlighting

During my short tenure under the CSS tag, I've noticed that code-prettify seems to interpet a naked `#` character as the beginning of a comment, for example:

```
#footer a.footA {
    color: #6bc2ef;
}
```

The first two lines would be greyed out after their '#' characters, which do not commence comments, but prefix an element ID and a color value, respectively. Is this something totally out of SO's control? Are there really more than a couple of languages that use `#` for comments?

> See [Unable to style an anchor tag? Someone explain why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9303101/unable-to-style-an-anchor-tag-someone-explain-why/9303133#9303133) for **ample** examples.

On a side note, why doesn't meta seem to code-prettify?

Comment: Related: [What's happening to syntax highlighting for \[css\] questions?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/121816)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is because the default highlighting for those tags is to auto-detect the language (presumably since posts in "webby" tags tend to contain code samples in several languages), and it doesn't always get it right. You can fix this by adding an explicit language annotation before the code block.

```
<!-- language: lang-css -->

    .footA:hover {
        color: #6bc2ef; !important
    }
```

This will cause the correct highlighting to be used which means both no graying out, and as a bonus you get highlighted keywords as well.