# Hex color values are treated as commented out

Tags: bug, stack-overflow, design

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What's happening to syntax highlighting for [css] questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/121816/whats-happening-to-syntax-highlighting-for-css-questions)

I often see the code syntax interpreting a hex color value in a CSS statement as a comment and then turning the rest of the line into a comment, as in [this recent question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9924915/combine-css-lines-into-one), although I could not duplicate below.

```
.whatever { text-align:center; color: #ffffff; font-size:16px; }
```

What causes this in some scenarios and can it be fixed, or is there already a way to prevent that?

Edit: It looks like the linked question has classes of "default prettyprint" and mine above has classes of "lang-css prettyprint". So I think I understand the root cause, but not how to prevent that when asking a question or edit a quesion that already has it.

Comment: `<!-- language: lang-css -->` makes it work properly.

Comment: See linked discussion - this is tricky, because css is so often paired with HTML (but not tagged as such).

Comment: You can override it like [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/63800/interface-options-for-specifying-language-prettify)

Comment: @Shog9 Thanks. Searched for similar questions but did not see it. (Didn't think another question on this topic would not use the word "comment"! :)