# I can't unstar a chat message that I pinned and somebody else later unpinned

Tags: support, chat, owner

Some months ago, I linked to [one of my other meta posts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/121816/whats-happening-to-syntax-highlighting-for-css-questions) in the CSS chat room and [pinned the announcement](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/2591532#2591532) in case anybody who cared happened to drop by:

> In case anybody else noticed that [css](/questions/tagged/css) questions are now highlighted a little differently, I'm actively investigating this; here's the meta thread

It was unpinned quite some time ago by one of the other room owners. I don't need it anymore anyway since the issue has been [settled to some extent](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/121816/whats-happening-to-syntax-highlighting-for-css-questions/122712#122712). I notice, however, that it's still visible in the starred list, with the only regular (not pinned) star being my own:

[image]

When I try to click on the star to unstar it, chat thinks I'm trying to do otherwise and simply tells me I can't star my own messages.

I can easily delete this message, but I'd very much like to unstar it instead, thankyouverymuch.

Comment: Note that pinned messages get auto-unpinned after two weeks.

Comment: @Shog9: I'm not asking if it's intended that I'm allowed to star my own messages by pinning them. I'm asking why I can't unstar my messages after pinning them (at least not the usual way of unstarring interesting messages).

Comment: Oh, right... Got distracted by all the fake-imitation-token-currency.

Answer (score 21):

If you're able to *pin* a message in a room, you can also *cancel stars* on it:

[image: What the action looks like]

IIRC, you'll also need to do this if *you* pin and then unpin the message. Yup, that's right - moderators (and room owners, AFAIK) *can* star their own messages using this odd hack. Unless, of course, your reporting it here gets that fixed.

*I would've gotten away with it too, if it weren't for that meddling kid!*

Comment: I wasn't aware of that option. Thanks.

Comment: The "when pinning, you get to star your own message" exception was a deliberate decision.

Comment: OUTSTANDING! @balpha

Comment: Is @balpha also saying this is the only intended way to unstar my own messages?