# Can not unstar own message in chat

Tags: bug, chat, chat-stars

I accidently pinned my own message. I managed to unpin it, but it still remained as starred.

When I try to unstar the message I get a message saying that I can not star my own message, and the message remains starred.

So there are two issues here:

1. The error message is incorrect, and;
2. It is not possible to unstar the message.

Here is a screenshot:

[image: Can not unstar my own message]

FWIW, I am the room owner.

Comment: You're trying to unstar or clear stars? You should be able to clear stars. I ask because you have the pane open to clear stars (bottom right corner there).

Comment: Isn't it good to have stars?

Comment: @U9-Forward it seems rather self-congratulatory... :-). Also the message is pointless. I didn't mean for it to be started. It appears to have become starred when I accidentally pinned it.

Comment: @Greenonline Haha, lol :-)

Answer (score 5):

The solution here, since you're a mod (and a room owner, but that's not necessary since you're a mod) is to clear the stars entirely. You do that on the pane you have open in the right column, the link that says "cancel stars".

[image: Message info box with options including cancel stars in lower right corner, which is circled with a red freehand circle.]

If yours is the *only* star, this is the simple solution. If someone else also starred the message, then you may not want to use this since it will also remove theirs... but if someone else starred it, your star isn't doing much harm.

And, since the only people who can get into this situation are mods or ROs, the solution will work for everyone who needs to unstar their own chat message.

Comment: Thanks Catha, but this seems like a work around rather than a bug fix. Useful nevertheless and I'll give it a try later and report back. So, this also works if you're a RO but not a mod too?

Comment: Yep but that's all I've got for you and it's likely the only option you'll have any time soon. To be honest, we've got a ton of stuff in the queue and chat tends to get little attention unless it's something that happens all the time and this... well, doesn't... at least, not as far as I'm aware.

Comment: @Greenonline considering almost identical answer was given [almost seven years ago](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/134858), I'm pretty sure we won't see any change in the next 6-8 years as well.

Comment: @ShadowWizard - Good point...  Thanks for pointing out the dupe :-)