# CSS syntax highlighting isn't right with # symbol

Tags: bug, syntax-highlighting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What’s happening to syntax highlighting for [css] questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/121816/whats-happening-to-syntax-highlighting-for-css-questions)

The problematic question is [Conflict with CSS Files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14183459/conflict-with-css-files)

lines starting with `#` symbol are completely gray - and hence the keywords does not highlight correctly.

It looks like it treats posts with only the [css] tag some language which considers `#` as start of comment...

Comment: Whomever voted his as off-topic should slow down a little.. :-P

Comment: I've added a highlighting hint, that made it render okay. Definitely odd that the tag didn't do it, though.

Comment: Looks like a bug in the prettify library, adding proper tag.

Comment: @DanielFischer It's set to `lang-default` because of the reasons outlined in ^

Comment: @TimStone Yes, **you** would know that.