# <!-- language: css --> markdown doesn't work properly

Tags: support, markdown, syntax-highlighting

Based on https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#syntax-highlighting I shouldn't need to give the `lang-` prefix when specifying a language for a tag, however this doesn't appear to be the case for CSS.

This is the result of specifying just `<!-- language: css -->` on a block of code:

[image: css no prefix]

Notice how the IDs (`#`) are being treated as comments rather than style declarations, and there is no nice formatting on the property names.

This is the result of specifying `<!-- language: lang-css -->` on the same block of code:

[image: css with prefix]

I'm not 100% sure if this is a problem, but if it is: can this be *fixed*?

Comment: You need to have the [css] tag in the question in order to use `<!-- language: css -->`.

Comment: @Antony this isn't the case. http://stackoverflow.com/q/16845844/1317805 is the question that code block is from and that question does have the CSS tag.

Comment: `<!-- language: css -->` works on your question here without any code related tags.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I shouldn't need to give the `lang-` prefix when specifying a language for a tag

Not exactly. What the help says is that you can use the `lang-` prefix or

> ...you can specify a tag, and the **syntax highlighting language associated with this tag** will be used

(emphasis mine)

The syntax highlighting association for the [css](/questions/tagged/css) tag is the default highlighter, not the `lang-css` one.

Comment: In that case, can the highlighting association be changed to point to the `lang-css` one? It's not like the CSS tag isn't popular.

Comment: You'll want to take a look at the discussion on [What's happening to syntax highlighting for \[css\] questions?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/121816) for why this is the current behaviour.

Comment: @JamesDonnelly: There is no highlighting association for the CSS tag because posts in that tag typically also have some HTML in them, and you don't want that to be highlighted as CSS.

Comment: Hmm I see. Thanks, @TimStone.