# Use CSS syntax highlighting when a question tagged with [css] has no other tags with syntax highlighting

Tags: feature-request, syntax-highlighting

Related:

- [Do we auto-detect and highlight CSS for questions tagged CSS?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184781/do-we-auto-detect-and-highlight-css-for-questions-tagged-css?lq=1)
- [What's happening to syntax highlighting for [css] questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/121816/whats-happening-to-syntax-highlighting-for-css-questions)

When asking a question tagged only with [css](/questions/tagged/css), there is currently no auto syntax highlighting. `<!-- language: lang-css -->` is required to get the highlighting.

I'm aware of the issues surrounding auto highlighting for this tag, but can we apply it when there are no other tags that would cause auto highlighting?