# Bash count Syntax Highlighting problem

Tags: discussion, bug, syntax-highlighting

for example:

[Is there a bash command that can tell the size of a shell variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4988155/is-there-a-bash-command-that-can-tell-the-size-of-a-shell-variable)

has a few responses which involve the bash `${#x}` construct.  It incorrectly treats the hash like a comment.

Questions:

1) What engine is used for syntax highlighting?

2) If SE an external engine, is there a way that we lowly users can make upstream changes that could be pushed?

Comment: See [Changes to syntax highlighting](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/72082/changes-to-syntax-highlighting) about which engine is used (Google Prettify).

Comment: Also note that the tags `shell` and `bash` seem to have conflicting syntax rules, which reverts back to `default` = "let prettify guess what language it is". I removed the `shell` tag from your question, but this did not change anything. Looks like a Prettify bug.

Comment: @Paulo if we push changes to prettify, will SO pick them up?

Comment: I would suppose that this is the case. At least, this is much more probable than SE making a local change to fix this. But to be sure, we would need an SE employee to confirm.

Comment: [This code](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12621739/1468366) is affected as well, as it uses `$#`. Did someone take this upstream already? If so, do you have any pointers where we can monitor progress?

Comment: Looking at the referenced post, it seems the issue is resolved now. Do you want to adjust the tags accordingly?

Answer (score 2):

Google Prettify has an [issue](http://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/issues/detail?id=165) which [indicates](http://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/issues/detail?id=165#c6) that this is now fixed by a [commit from 2012-07-06](http://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/source/detail?r=223).
Can we please get this fix installed on SO to check whether it works as advertised?