# Can Octave/Matlab code get syntax highlighting?

Tags: feature-request, syntax-highlighting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Proposition to add another language syntax (MATLAB) by custom google-code-prettify script](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/123274/proposition-to-add-another-language-syntax-matlab-by-custom-google-code-pretti)

This was [previously requested](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/72082/changes-to-syntax-highlighting/77745#77745) but apparently never got done. Can questions marked [octave](/questions/tagged/octave) and [matlab](/questions/tagged/matlab) please have default syntax highlighting applied? See, for example, [How can I compute all factors of a number in octave (not just prime factors)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7779815/how-can-i-compute-all-factors-of-a-number-in-octave-not-just-prime-factors) on SO.

Comment: This has been done, but it still looks pretty bad as of Aug 2015.