# Add syntax highlighting for the MATLAB language

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, stack-overflow, syntax-highlighting

MATLAB language posts don't look good under `google-code-prettify`.  As far as I understand from [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/109441/can-octave-matlab-code-get-syntax-highlighting) post, MATLAB is currently highlighted by using the default language syntax.

For example, you can see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8790059/how-to-find-out-how-many-figures-are-currently-opened/8790218#8790218) question. Since `%` is the standard in MATLAB to write comments, but it is not known, comments look weird.

However, it has an option to write a custom `.js` that defines a new language. I was thinking about writing myself a custom `.js` that will do the trick, but before I do that, I want to make sure that it will actually be **used** in Stack Overflow, and my effort is not in vain.

Is it possible to add custom google-code-prettify `.js` files to the server of Stack Overflow?

Comment: We do have custom prettify javascript for a few languages, TeX for one.  Ideally it'd be contributed back to [prettify](http://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/).

Comment: I've been looking for a simple MATLAB highlighter but so far I've had no luck. Did you do your custom prettify? It would be nice if you post it somewhere if you did.

Comment: Don't forget Octave.

Comment: @KevinMontrose, it's been integrated into prettify. Could you look at updating the version used on Stack Overflow?

Comment: @KevinMontrose, over a year later, it has yet to be integrated on Stack Overflow. Is that a possibility, for us MatLab developpers?

Comment: @KevinMontrose With the risk of being repetitive: This would be an awesome feature for the Matlab tag, that still doesn't have syntax highlight even if `TeX` has. And `TeX` is now off topic in stackoverflow...

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Matlab syntax support is rolling in.

This is basic syntax support without keywords, as these add a lot to the size of the highlighter and do not gzip well at all.

Still - comments should be comments and basic highlighting should work as expected.

Comment: Wonderful news! Thanks you for taking the time to add the MATLAB support. I'll see if I can get the "Lite" version included upstream in google/code-prettify in addition to the regular version, that way it would be easier to pull changes in the future.

Comment: Thanks for writing it in the first place!

Comment: \o/ It's so working! All my posts suddenly became gorgeous!

Answer (score 34):

Back in May 2012, I started a [project](https://github.com/amroamroamro/prettify-matlab) hosted on GitHub that implements MATLAB syntax highlighting for google-code-prettify (released under the MIT License). See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10448123/97160) for the initial announcement, plus there was some discussion in the [MATLAB chat room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2793/matlab).

It comes in two flavors, one that detects and stylize all core MATLAB functions (plus functions from select toolboxes), and another that doesn't (mainly to keep file size to a minimum).

Should *Stack Overflow* choose to use it, it's as simple as serving an additional [JavaScript file](https://github.com/amroamroamro/prettify-matlab/blob/master/js/lang-matlab.js), which extends the code prettifier to handle MATLAB code.

For the time being, I created a userscript version so people can try it immediately (I have been using it myself for some time now).

You can install the userscript directly from the link https://github.com/amroamroamro/prettify-matlab/raw/master/js/prettify-matlab.user.js or choose the "lite"
version, https://github.com/amroamroamro/prettify-matlab/raw/no_functions/js/prettify-matlab.user.js.

Comment: I have been using this very happily until now, when Google decided to disable any extensions that didn't originate from their store, and there's no way to re-enable them. It looks like the only way for people using Chrome to use this is for the developer (s) to upload the extension into the Chrome Web Store.

Comment: @am304: Firefox is my main browser, so I hadn't noticed the change.. Apparently [the workaround](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5258989) is easy: just download the userscript as a regular file (`prettify-matlab.user.js`), go to your extensions page (`chrome://extensions/`), and drag/drop the file onto the page. That will bypass the store-only limitation. I just tried it and it worked fine. Alternatively you could install the Tampermonkey extension, this is like Greasemonkey for Chrome browsers (it's a must have extension for anyone who uses userscripts regularly).

Comment: See here for detailed instructions for various browsers: http://stackapps.com/tags/script/info

Comment: I tried it and it didn't work. That's what I used to do but this week-end Google pushed a new version of Chrome that doesn't allow you to do that (Version 35.0.1916.153 m).

Comment: Update: it looks like if I first delete the existing extension and drag & drop the file again, it works. I'll try closing and re-starting Chrome next to see if it holds.

Comment: Nope. I restarted Chrome and it got disabled again, without the possibility to re-enable it.

Comment: I just tried it on a freshly installed Chrome (latest v35), and now I see what mean. Apparently Google has started blocking all extensions on Windows not installed from the Web Store (even permanently disables installed ones too!), except installs via [enterprise policy](https://support.google.com/chrome/a/answer/188453) or [developer mode](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/getstarted.html#unpacked) (unfortunately those are not the most straightforward ways). IMO the easiest method to working with userscripts is to just install the Tampermonkey extension to manage all your userscripts.

Comment: Here is someone who asked about the same problem: http://superuser.com/questions/767286/re-enable-extensions-not-coming-from-chrome-web-store-on-chrome-v35-with-enhan

Comment: Thanks, I think I have managed to get Tampermonkey to work...

Comment: @Amro I'm not sure if you've seen this: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/278141/highlight-js-for-real-please/279361#comment905392_279361 It appears the size of the prettify script is a problem.

Comment: Oded also notes in a subsequent comment that if it's possible to deflate the thing by throwing away features, they would consider it if its final size was comparable to other languages. (cc @beaker)