# Code formatting for Matlab

Tags: feature-request, code-formatting, syntax-highlighting

I have noticed that when posting MATLAB code to StackOverflow that the formatting appears rather inhomogeneous, at least when viewed from my browser (OSX Safari and Firefox).

I've searched around for details on a possible solution, hoping to make the code look as nice as the corresponding C or C++ code; I did find [this discussion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/123274/add-syntax-highlighting-for-the-matlab-language).  Any new plans or news on this?  There was mention of a GitHub project that implements the MATLAB syntax highlighting.

The main culprit appears to be the MATLAB comment character, %. As a workaround I find myself just using regular text to explain what I would normally leave as a code comment, which makes the overall post look disjointed; anyone wishing to simply copy and paste such code examples would then have to insert the comment characters themselves, or copy and paste pieces at a time.

Are there any current plans or updates to have the code formatters better accommodate Matlab code?

Thanks.

Comment: I would also appreciate a better formatting environment for MATLAB code. Especially the commented out portions.