# What is the technology used for syntax highlighting?

Tags: discussion, syntax-highlighting, spelling

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Changes to syntax highlighting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/72082/changes-to-syntax-highlighting)

Some languages are not managed by the coloration system, such as nvelocity.

What is the technology used by Stack Overflow for syntax highlighting, and what are the languages which are detected?

Comment: Spell checking? Did I miss something?

Comment: @Asylum - no. Stack Exchange doesn't do spell checking. Your browser probably does though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As reported in [Changes to syntax highlighting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/72082/changes-to-syntax-highlighting), syntax highlighting is done with [Google Code Prettify](http://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/), and the known language IDs are the following ones: apollo, bsh, c, cc, cpp, cs, csh, css, cyc, cv, go, hs, htm, html, java, js, lisp, lua, m, ml, mxml, perl, pl, pm, proto, py, rb, scala, sh, sql, vb, vhdl, wiki, yaml, xhtml, xml, xsl.

The syntax highlighting applied is the one associated to the tags being used (moderators can associate a syntax highlighting to every tag), the default syntax highlighting that is set by Stack Exchange employers for each individual SE site (the default one used on Stack Overflow is probably different from the one used on [Drupal Answers](http://drupal.stackexchange.com)), or the one that is set using an HTML comment similar to the following one:

```
<!-- language: lang-c -->
```

Comment: <!-- language: lang-yaml --> does nothing.

Answer (score 2):

Stack Exchange uses [Google Code Prettify](https://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/). See the [Syntax Highlighting](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#syntax-highlighting) section of the editing help page for more info.