# Can [sencha-touch]-tagged posts be associated with lang-js for Prettify purposes?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, syntax-highlighting

[sencha-touch](/questions/tagged/sencha-touch) (along with almost all of the Sencha tags) will all have their code examples written in [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript).

Since the language type for prettify is inferred from the tags, I'm suggesting that Sencha Touch, and other Sencha tags be recognized by prettify as `lang-js`.

Comment: For reference, [this post explains how highlighting hints can be associated with tags](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/72082/changes-to-syntax-highlighting).

Comment: @hammar remember that any diamond mod can edit the highlighting rule for a given tag.. either "none", "automatic", "specific-language".. etc

Comment: @JeffAtwood I'd still like to see this happen. There are tons of JS libraries out there with SO tags. Those libraries should be prettified without the need to specify [tag:javascript] or manually `lang-js`.

Answer (score 1):

On Stack Overflow, the language associated to a question is, by default, automatically detected. The automatic detection is normally good at guessing what language is used, when the language has a C/C++ syntax, or it is HTML/XML. There are few cases where the code could be interpreted as being written in a different language, such when the used snippet is using constructs that are used from more than one language.

Apart those cases, there is normally no need to associate a language to a specific languages. In the specific case, I am not sure there is the need to set "lang-js" as language associated with any JavaScript library tag, when it is possible to add [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript) to those questions.
What would happen if the library is ported to other languages, and [sencha-touch](/questions/tagged/sencha-touch) is used also for the porting to another language?

Comment: I had to add `lang-js` to [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8546141/124069) in order for syntax highlighting to work.

Comment: The alternative is using [tag:javascript] for questions that are about JavaScript, like the one you are referring.

Comment: This is of course an option. But not **everyone** will, yet **every** question tagged [tag:sencha-touch] will require `lang-js` syntax highlighting for code examples