# Enable syntax highlighting for the "pascal" tag

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, stack-overflow, syntax-highlighting

A little over a year ago [I reported](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/76969/33732) that [pascal](/questions/tagged/pascal) should have syntax highlighting, but there seems to have been no reaction. Can someone please enable default syntax highlighting for that tag?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Done.

(and I've locked that other question, since it's too easy to miss new answers at this point)

Comment: Its set for "default".  And Pascal doesn't appear to be in the list of supported languages...

Comment: Thanks. [Adding specific Pascal support to Prettify](http://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/issues/detail?id=137) is a separate task, @Won't. Once that's taken care of, I'll ask for the tag configurations to be updated. Meanwhile, something's better than nothing.

Comment: Maybe you could edit that other question, too, so that where it currently says "post your diffs as answers," it would instead call for new questions if there are changes required.