# MVVM tag language hint seems off

Tags: support, stack-overflow, tags, syntax-highlighting

Been wondering about this for a while now, the [mvvm](/questions/tagged/mvvm) tag seems to have an XML-language-hint.

[Here is an example question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9284026/bind-datatable-with-datagrid-in-wpf-mvvm) which has both C# and XAML code, as one can see the C# is also in XML highlighting (espcially visible on generics like `List<DataColumn>`). It would probably be better if it behaved like the [wpf](/questions/tagged/wpf) tag (which has a [*default* hint](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/72082/changes-to-syntax-highlighting)).

Comment: But surely MVVM can apply to other languages than C# - or am I missing something?

Comment: @ChrisF: That is why i am saying there should be no association at all.

Comment: Ah - I am missing something then.

Comment: Isn't just the xml highlighted? So basically the xaml tag formats xml code.

Comment: @gideon: There is no XAML tag, that's the point, if there was i wouldn't be surprised.

Comment: oh jeez right, perusing SO for the millionth time after work does do things to your eyes I think!  Agreed @H.B. your post makes sense.

Comment: As usual in these cases, I have to first ask if the change would break any existing syntax highlighting, and if so, how extensive the damage would be.

Comment: @mmyers: Well, the XAML highlighting might suffer as currectly the c#+mvvm combination gets C# and XAML highlighted, if that change would be made the XAML would be highlighted as c# (which does not seem any worse than in many cases C# getting highlighted as XML).

Answer (score 2):

Eh, I'm not sure about this.

As mentioned in the comments, by changing [mvvm](/questions/tagged/mvvm) to lang-default, [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23) will end up being the only tag with a specific language hint, causing *every* code block (including the XAML) to be highlighted as C#. That's no good.

With lang-xml, a specific language hint, a question with *both* tags (and thus *both* language hints) will fall back to lang-default for highlighting. This allows each code block to be highlighted as appropriately as prettify thinks it can.

Personally, I don't think we should leave the question as is, with just the [mvvm](/questions/tagged/mvvm) tag alone. In fact, I went ahead and added the [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23) and [wpf](/questions/tagged/wpf) tags to it instead. After all, the language used in the question is C#, while MVVM is merely a pattern. It was probably given the lang-xml hint based on how MVVM is most prevalent in WPF/Silverlight application development, which uses XAML for views.