# How does Stack Overflow know how to style code blocks?

Tags: support, code-formatting, syntax-highlighting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Changes to syntax highlighting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/72082/changes-to-syntax-highlighting)

Code blocks posted on Stack Overflow get marked up with an assortment of colors based on the languages they're written in. How does SO know which colors go with which pieces of code?

Comment: Not sure what SO uses, but [Pygments](http://pygments.org/ "Pygments") is considered the best code highlighter by many.

Comment: [Google Code's Prettify](http://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/)

Comment: This is covered in the Stack Overflow FAQ.