# Is it possible to expand tag-based highlighting for Java on javafx and javafx-2 tags?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tags, tag-highlighting

Is using [java](/questions/tagged/java) as well considered good practice for this kind of questions? It sounds a bit redundant.

For example: [JavaFX 2.0 SplitPane no longer working as expected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6834256/javafx-2-0-splitpane-no-longer-working-as-expected)

UPDATE: it's not a problem with a particular question. It's a general issue with [javafx-2](/questions/tagged/javafx-2) questions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think I fixed it.  If you look at these questions you'll see the code blocks are now highlighted:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10232071/access-cell-factory (tagged [javafx](/questions/tagged/javafx))
- [Change TreeItem height when it resized](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10233162/change-treeitem-height-when-it-resized) (tagged [javafx-2](/questions/tagged/javafx-2))

Comment: thanks! Can you, please, explain how? Is it some kind of privilege?

Comment: @SergeyGrinev: Actually, I have no idea when users get that privilege.    I'm going to guess it has something to do with creating/editing wikis, so around the 5k level.

Comment: No, only moderators and developers are able to change code highlighting for tags. I believe Jeff mentioned this a few times ([here's one](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/72163/137537)).

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn: kk

Comment: @Won't same issue now with [javafx-8] tag, can you please update it as well?

Comment: @SergeyGrinev: Nope.  You'll have to ask a new question, or flag a question tagged, select Other, then leave the details in the flag message.

Comment: Thanks, I've posted http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/234535/

Answer (score 1):

If the code **is** java, just tag it [java](/questions/tagged/java) as well ^_^

Comment: It has been **DONE** ^_^

Comment: i can tag it, but a lot of submitters don't do this given that "java" word is exact part of "javafx"