# Add syntax highlighting for posts with the [go] tag

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, syntax-highlighting

Posts with the [go](/questions/tagged/go) tag currently do not have syntax highlighting applied.  When I manually set a code block's language with `<!-- language: lang-go -->`, the syntax highlighting works as expected.

As I understand things from reading [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/72082/187298), the implication is that the [go](/questions/tagged/go) tag currently has a `null` syntax highlighting hint.

I propose that the [go](/questions/tagged/go) tag have its highlighting hint set to `lang-go`.

Comment: According to that same post, prettify doesn't have a syntax highlighting scheme for Go, so `lang-go` doesn't exist. It looks like `lang-go` is being treated as `lang-default` when you add that hint to a post.

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn It's listed in that post as an extension, but it wasn't clear if that meant it was supported here or not. I pondered this, and then I noticed that Scala is also listed as an extension (both in that post and in the current Prettify repo), and Scala is one of the ones that Jeff included in his initial set. So my assumption is that the extensions *are* supported. If I'm only seeing the default formatting, that's still much better than *no* formatting, and my proposal remains the same.

Comment: Oh, I didn't spot that. I checked, though, and don't see lang-go in the list of supported schemes.

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn Well, if it makes more sense to set the hint to `default`, then that works just as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Although prettify lists Go as one of the extensions to its existing set of syntax highlighting scheme, I'm not seeing it in the list of schemes for the [go](/questions/tagged/go) tag.

I can only assume that `lang-go` is essentially being treated as `lang-default` when you add the hint to a post in that case. I've changed it so posts tagged [go](/questions/tagged/go) should now be syntax-highlighted.

Comment: Indeed, it works -- that was fast!  Thanks for your help; this was a very pleasant first foray into the land of meta.

Comment: I'm not getting any syntax highlighting when marking up a code block with `<!-- language: lang-go -->` ...has this regressed?

Comment: UPDATE: `<!-- language: lang-golang -->` works!