# Add the Go extension to syntax highlighting

Tags: feature-request, syntax-highlighting

In my answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19078977/can-i-use-gos-xml-unmarshall-for-ordered-polymorphic-types) question on StackOverflow, I tried to make a language hint:

```
<!-- language: lang-go -->
```

While it stopped trying to treat the code as XML, it didn't do much prettifying at all.

In the [Prettifier FAQ](http://google-code-prettify.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/README.html), it is stated that Go is available via extension. Can this extension be added to Stack Exchange's deployed version for syntax highlighting?

Comment: FYI, that extension has comments in a different color and nothing else, looking at the linked javascript file.  Not sure how helpful it'd be.

Comment: Related to http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/139114/add-syntax-highlighting-for-posts-with-the-go-tag?rq=1, but it looks like Go has been added as a properly supported language since then.