# Problems with Python syntax highlight in some cases?

Tags: support, syntax-highlighting

While browsing StackOverflow, I stumbled onto [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11641980/440558), and noticed that the syntax highlighting was off, even though the code in the question was formatted properly and the question was properly tagged.

Are there some (edge?) cases where the syntax highlighting will not work?

Also, the highlighting in answers to that question doesn't work as well.

Comment: I've added the `<!-- language: lang-python -->` at the start of the code block and it seems to have sorted it.  Sorry if this cancels your bug report :)  You can still see the problem [in the revisions though](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/11641980/revisions#rev3d3ca620-e074-4347-888f-78911ddd5a12)...

Comment: Actually, in the revisions, the code *is* correctly highlighted. I'm not saying there wasn't a problem before you inserted the language hint, just that you can no longer see it now.

Comment: Ah, no, I see it now. It's being highlighted as SQL instead of python.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two tags on that question that have language hints associated with them: [python](/questions/tagged/python) and [database](/questions/tagged/database). The latter won in this case and the code was highlighted as SQL. See [Changes to syntax highlighting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/72082/changes-to-syntax-highlighting) on how tags dictate language hints for syntax highlighting.

The correct way to fix it is to insert an explicit language hint, which Lix already did. See [How do I format my code blocks?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks)

Comment: Is there a list of tag-to-implicit-highlighting-hint?

Comment: Heh, it's funny that the database tag won the syntax highlighting, but that the python tag won when computing the page title. :)

Comment: @nhahtdh: I added a link to the original post on syntax highlighting on SE sites.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: I have a feeling that it is outdated.

Comment: The interesting thing is that according to [Jeff's original post on syntax highlighting](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/72082/changes-to-syntax-highlighting) it's prettify that made this decision; two tags with language hints means that SE let's prettify decide instead of setting a language, apparently.

Comment: @nhahtdh: moderators can attach a language hint to tags, but there is no public list.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: Shouldn't it be made public? Even just for the purpose of referencing?

Comment: @nhahtdh: Open a feature request question here on meta and see if people agree.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: OK. Probably later. Kinda low on energy right now and I don't want to write a crappy question.