# Inject explicit prettify hint for current default language into new posts

Tags: feature-request, syntax-highlighting

Since learning that one can give Prettify [language hints](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#syntax-highlighting), I've been quite careful to specify such whenever I post code in a non-default language; however, out of laziness (or conciseness), I've omitted explicit hints whenever my code uses the then-current default.

On occasion, I've noticed that a question's tags have been edited after my post, resulting in a different and unintended formatting being applied.

I was about to suggest that the default language at the time of a post be retained through tag edits, but then I discovered that a certain "Jon Skeet" (of course; who else?) [did that years ago](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/72091/161492).  Despite the numerous upvotes, it seems his suggestion never got implemented (perhaps because the question was only a [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion) rather than a [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request), or perhaps because it has since been locked).

Mr Skeet noted that:

> edits make this even more complicated... should an edit take on the new default or not?

**I propose that upon being first submitted, SO automatically prepend every post with a `<!-- language-all: ... -->` hint; subsequent edits would then be able to modify the default if so desired.**

Historical posts could be similarly updated to the now-current defaults without harm.