# Please set ember.js tags to use JavaScript syntax highlighting

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, stack-overflow, tags, syntax-highlighting

[Ember](http://emberjs.com/) is a JavaScript-based MVC framework and its tag, [ember.js](/questions/tagged/ember.js), probably should use default to using JavaScript syntax highlighting. I'm not sure if this is the best place to ask this; if it's not, please direct me to a more appropriate solution.

Comment: I didn't even know the tags determined the default syntax highlighting. What happens when there's a mix?

Comment: I believe the first tag takes precedence.

Comment: People should probably be tagging it [tag:javascript] too. (And why does Ember get special treatment?)

Comment: @minitech: Indeed they should, but they **don't** :P

Comment: @Matt: So add it and/or tell them about it. I don't see how adding syntax highlighting defaults to frameworks helps anything.

Comment: @minitech: Sure we could, but I don't see the *harm* in adding the highlighting default?

Comment: ... Mmm although the JavaScript tag by itself isn't a *perfect* solution in this case... Embers' handlebar templating system creates its own issues: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12462381/i-dont-understand-this-block-helpers-example-from-the-handlebars-js-readme

Comment: @j08691: All the rules can be found here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/72082/changes-to-syntax-highlighting

Comment: @minitech: Ember hasn't been the only library to get special treatment. See jQuery (and [this highly relevant tweet](https://twitter.com/BoltClock/status/63609746057465856)).

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn: Well, jQuery's a language now. (- Oh, that's what the tweet says.)

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn - thanks for the link.

Comment: OK. It had been my understanding that items tagged with JavaScript should be about pure JavaScript not about any specific accompanying tools.  I guess I misunderstood that.  BTW, is manually specifying the pretty-print/syntax-highlighting no longer supported?  I tried to do it here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12193600/hello-world-in-ember-js-whats-wrong-here

Answer (score 1):

I set the highlighting on the [ember.js](/questions/tagged/ember.js) tag to "default".

Your [example question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12193600/hello-world-in-ember-js-whats-wrong-here) looks properly highlighted to me now after I rolled back your edit that added the [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript) tag.